# While running application by IDEA Android Studio virtual device is not launched

Tags: android-studio, emulation, android-virtual-device

I have created blank full screen application using Android Studio. When I run the app I select predefined virtual device than nothing happens. IDE just waits for the device which is not created. Please look at the screenshot please.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If your virtual device uses x86 CPU/ABI, the cause may be that you do not have HAXM installer on your computer.

I had a similar problem; after I installed the HAXM package (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26355645/error-in-launching-avd) for instructions), the emulator launched.