# Error in launching AVD with AMD processor

Tags: android, intel, android-virtual-device, haxm

I have Windows 8.1 pro with an AMD processor. I installed the Android SDK and Eclipse. It works but the problem is that when I Create AVD and launch it shows this error:

> emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!
>    Please ensure Intel HAXM is properly installed and usable.
>    CPU acceleration status: HAX kernel module is not installed!

I have already installed Intel Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager and I have enabled Virtual modulation from the boot menu, but it's still not working.

Comment: In case you don't see the package "Intel x86 emulator accelerator" under Extras, go to Tools, Options and check the "Force https://" option and relaunch the SDK Manager.

Comment: I have `Windows 8.1` with an `Inter Core i7`. Getting the same error message.

Comment: @asgs Coudn't find menu "Tools > Options" in Android Studio 1.4.1. Do you know if this menu option has been removed or moved to another menu?

Comment: @UlyssesAlves That is in SDK manager.

Comment: I have installed the SDK on two machines. On one (Thinkpad) this option is not even checked but the emulator works fine, on the other (Toshiba) I see this over and over even after I did all the steps on this page but I cannot get to the BIOS try what may so I gave up. My question - why does it work different on different machines ?

Comment: Error message also present in Win10 1511.

Comment: Also see [Emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29136173/608639), [Error in launching AVD with AMD processor](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26355645/608639), [Error while starting emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34282243/608639), etc.

Comment: HAXM has been open sourced: https://github.com/intel/haxm

Comment: If it is already installed and you get the same error, enable virtualization in BIOS.

Comment: Had used this question in the past.  This time it didn't work (same machine).  This time, a HAXM uninstall/reinstall fixed it.

Answer (score 846):

Make sure you have installed `HAXM installer` on your SDK Manager.

[image: Android SDK Manager]

After you download it and make sure you **run** the setup located in:
**{SDK_FOLDER}\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager\intelhaxm.exe**

Note: in Android Studio, the command "intelhaxm.exe" has been changed to "intelhaxm-android.exe"

If you get the error **"VT not supported"** during the installation disable Hyper-V on windows features. You can execute this command `dism.exe /Online /Disable-Feature:Microsoft-Hyper-V`. You will also need "Virtualization Technology" to be enabled on your BIOS

Comment: Additional info: https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/installation-instructions-for-intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-windows

Comment: Aside from Genymotion is there no alternatives for people with AMD instead of Intel?

Comment: See Dash answer for that. You need Linux/Mac as far as I know

Comment: @jj_ have you tried reading the genymotion faq? Because that answers all your questions. Also this is not a genymotion related problem and therefore has nothing to do with that emulator.

Comment: I once finished installation and configuration of android studio i got the same error. How to get the configuration screen again?

Comment: See this video, it solves my probleme https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ar9_FUFJhDU

Comment: It worked for me after running intelhaxm-android.exe. It wasn't immediately clear to me that the SDK was installed under my user folder, but a file search solved that problem.  The weird thing is that I already ran this once when I initially installed HAXM. For the benefit of others who also had trouble finding it, mine was located at C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager\intelhaxm-android.exe

Comment: I followed exactly each step and still cant run the install because of `VT not supported` :/

Comment: For those who have disabled Hyper-V, turned on VT in BIOS and see using [Intel PIU](http://www.intel.com/support/processors/tools/piu/sb/CS-014921.htm) it is running and still has the same VT-x error - try to take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21725061/966932) - worked for me (Avast features blocked the VT-x).

Comment: Also, be sure your processor supports VT. My Intel T4400 does not I discovered from this site: ark.intel.com but that's ok, I found a cheap used Android phone for development purposes.

Comment: dism.exe /Online /Disable-Feature:Microsoft-Hyper-V     ---- This command does not work, saying:  Feature name Microsoft-Hyper-V is unknown. A Windows feature name was not recognized. Use the /Get-Features option to find the name of the feature in the image and try the command again.

Comment: VT-x is active, but my system is x64 how can I do to install intelhaxm-android.exe? The error is this: http://s18.postimg.org/kgtu90rqx/Immagine.png

Comment: Finally! I didn't have VT-x settings in bios, but processor support it, so I thougth it was disabled by default and you cannot change it unless you change the settings via setup_var, but this can lead to full brick. I bought this PC few days ago for 1000€, and bricking so expensive computer is no fun. I had no idea whatsoever Hyper-V can disable VT.

Comment: On Mac: `IntelHAXM_[versionNumber].dmg`

Comment: Haxm Installer told me that I have a pc that could run ist, but that I needed to activate hyper-v. But hyper-v is not available for win 10 home. Am I stuck with ARM then?

Comment: Have you tried `DISM /Online /Enable-Feature /All /FeatureName:Microsoft-Hyper-V`@lucidbrot

Comment: **Update Solution** follow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50812600/haxm-error-in-android-studio-3-0-with-windows-requires-a-digitally-signed-driver

Answer (score 211):

1. Open SDK Manager and download **Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator** (HAXM installer) if you haven't.
2. Now go to your SDK directory (C:\users\username\AppData\Local\Android\sdk, generally). In this directory, go to **extras → Intel → Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager** and run the file named "**intelhaxm-android.exe**".

   > In case you get an error like "Intel virtualization technology
   >   (vt,vt-x) is not enabled", go to your BIOS settings and enable
   >   hardware virtualization.
3. Restart Android Studio and then try to start the AVD again.

It might take a minute or 2 to show the emulator window.

Comment: do you mean computer BIOS?

Comment: @binaryBaBa : Yes. In motherboard settings.

Comment: what might be the solution if the virtualization is not supported in my computer

Comment: @TaraGurung Then you should try GenyMotion emulator. It is not as heavy as the android studio emulator.

Comment: General path for the installer is - `C:\Users\<UserName>\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager`. I just extended it till the last part of the directory structure on a Windows 10 box.

Comment: I think the question was about AMD.   Intel HAXM doesn't work on AMD.

Answer (score 144):

If you're running Mac, as @pedro mentions ensure you have the HAXM installer dowloaded via the Android SDK Manager.

Next install it! In finder navigate to `/YOUR_SDK_PATH/extras/intel/Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager/`

Run and install the .mpgk in the following .dmg

- Yosemite: `IntelHAXM_1.1.0_for_10.10.dmg`
- Pre-yosemite:  `IntelHAXM_1.1.0_below_10.10.dmg`
- El Capitan: IntelHAXM_6.0.1.dmg - please install the IntelHAXM_6.0.1.mpgk file within - it will ask you if you want to reinstall it. Just say yes.

Example:

> ```
> $cd /YOUR_SDK_PATH/extras/intel/Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager/
> $open IntelHAXM_1.1.0_below_10.10.dmg
> ```

Comment: Recently upgraded to Android Studio on the mac and the SDK folder was placed in my Library/Android/ directory.

Comment: if you find this file on the terminal you can mount the dmg file with 'hdiutil attach IntelHAXM_1.1.0_for_10.10.dmg'

Comment: Pretty big issues with HAXM, latest Android Studio and MacOS it seems: https://github.com/intel/haxm/issues/403

Answer (score 107):

**First**, you must enable Intel virtualization technology from the BIOS:

[image]

**Second**, navigate to your SDK ...\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager:

[image]

Then install **intelhaxm-android.exe**.

Note that if you can't find this file in the directory, make sure you install the package from your SDK manager:

[image]

Comment: after install Intel Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager from Extras , install (double click) <sdk>/extras/intel/Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager/IntelHAXM.dmg

Comment: If you are running Avast and get block when installing intelhaxm-android.exe even if Intel Virtualization Technology from BIOS is enable. Try desinstall Avast launch again intelhaxm-android.exe then reinstall Avast. It worked for me.

Comment: Before enable VT in BIOS lets check whether your system support VT or not by run this [leomoon cpv application](http://leomoon.com/downloads/application/leomoon-cpu-v/) it will display both VT supported and enabled features

Answer (score 30):

**This resolves it for me:**

Go to (**C:\users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Android\sdk, generally**).

Then go to **Extras -> Intel -> Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager** and run the file named "intelhaxm-android.exe".

In case you get an error like "**Intel virtualization technology (vt,vt-x) is not enabled**", go to your BIOS settings and enable Hardware Virtualization.

***Restart your studio***

Answer (score 24):

**For AMD processors:**

You don't need Genymotion, just create a new Virtual Device and while selecting the system Image select the ABI as **armeabi** instead of the default x86 one.

[image]

Comment: I develop with Android Studio on a virtualized machine on cloud, but looks like my virtualized machine is created without support for Intel VT-x technology. Your answer helped me to run Android emulator with ARM images rather than x86 ones. However, it is very slow.

Answer (score 20):

I faced the same problem recently.

I installed the HAXM installer on your SDK Manager:

[image]

And then installed the latest Intel HAXM driver:

https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-end-user-license-agreement

And voila!!! The emulator works like a charm :)

Comment: Missing link for OS X: https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-end-user-license-agreement-macosx

Comment: In windows OS, I got the zip file extracted it and installed it and was able to start android emulator.

Answer (score 14):

For AMD processors:

Go to AVD manager and create a new virtual device as an ARM system image.

Answer (score 12):

So I am having this issue and it seems that unless you are on Linux you will not be able to use HAXM. [EDIT: this is if you have an AMD chip (non intel) of course as that is the issue]

As stated on the Android Site;

> Many modern CPUs provide extensions for running virtual machines (VMs)
>   more efficiently. Taking advantage of these extensions with the
>   Android emulator requires some additional configuration of your
>   development system, but can significantly improve the execution speed.
>   Before attempting to use this type of acceleration, you should first
>   determine if your development system’s CPU supports one of the
>   following virtualization extensions technologies:
>
> ```
> Intel Virtualization Technology (VT, VT-x, vmx) extensions
> ```
>
> ***>     AMD Virtualization (AMD-V, SVM) extensions (only supported for Linux)***

As others have mentioned Genymotion may be a solution.

Comment: `that unless you are on Linux you will not be able to use HAXM.` That's false. I'm on Windows and running HAXM with no problem.

Comment: If you have Intel it will work. If you don't have Intel it will not unless you are on Mac or Linux.

Answer (score 11):

I waste too much time on this, and none of the previous answers work. I find that [Avast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avast_Software#Consumer_desktop_products) is the issue!!! If you have Avast installed in your system, you have to:

> Go to settings tab --> troubleshooting, then you should UNCHECK the
>   "enable hardware-assisted virtualization"

Restart your PC and install the intelhaxm-android.exe if it is not installed. You can find it in `C:\Users\{YOUR USERNAME}\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager`

Answer (score 8):

For those who are using **Android Studio** based on Jetbrains:

1. Goto Tools > Android > SDK Manager
2. Under Extras --> select the checkbox Intel x86 Emulator Accelorator

For those who are unable to use Nexus AVD can also try using Generic AVD.

1. Goto Tools > Android > AVD Manager

Then create a new Genreic AVD with something like QVGA and use for your app. This AVD does not use hardware acceleration.

Answer (score 8):

I was facing this issue running the emulator inside Oracle VirtualBox. For me the solution was to modify the emulator to use an ARM CPU instead of x86.

Comment: You need to have intell x86 emulator accelerator installed to run x86 emulator. See my answer above. It might help.

Comment: For VMWare I enabled VT-x Emulation on the virtual machine settings and installed HAXM from extras folder

Answer (score 7):

You need to read (and post) the output of

```
sc query intelhaxm
```

as stated on http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#accel-vm

You open a command prompt window by right click on the start menu, choose execute and write 'cmd'.

See also [Android Emulator Doesn't Use HAXM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26316523/android-emulator-doesnt-use-haxm) .

If you cannot get the emulator to work you might want to try out an easier alternative: Genymotion - http://genymotion.com/

Answer (score 7):

First of all you should have Virtualization Enabled and you can do it from BIOS setting.

After that go to Control Panel\Programs and Click on "Turn Windows features on or off" option.

You will now have a pop up window, spot "Windows Hypervisor Platform" and enable it by checking the check box.

[image]
Restart your PC and now AVD should work without any issue.

Answer (score 6):

For **Android Studio 1.0.2**:

First make sure **Intel x86 emulator accelerator is installer**. Check it in your SDK Manager. If not, then install it from there.

Go to your Android SDK folder,
**{SDK_FOLDER}\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager**

There you will find **silent_install.bat**.

Run it. It will **create haxm_silent_run.log**. After that, close and restart your Android Studio and then run your app.

It will work. In case of a problem, check the haxm_silent_run.log file.

Answer (score 4):

As many other pointed out, Intel HAXM only supports Intel CPUs. Since Windows 1804 you can use Microsoft's Hyper-V instead of HAXM for the emulator. This also helps people who want to use Hyper-V for virtual machines as you need to disable hyper-v to run haxm.

Short version:

- install Windows Hypervisor Platform feature
- Update to Android Emulator 27.2.7 or above
- put WindowsHypervisorPlatform = on into C:\Users\your-username\.android\advancedFeatures.ini or start emulator or command line with -feature WindowsHypervisorPlatform
- enable IOMMU in your BIOS settings

Long version with more details:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2018/05/08/hyper-v-android-emulator-support/

Requirements docs:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/virtualization/hyper-v/system-requirements-for-hyper-v-on-windows

Comment: All the answers above that are actually irrelevant for Windows/AMD except this one.   Enabling windows hyperv, and enabling AMD IOMMU support in the BIOS results in accelerated performance on and AMD/Windows system.

Answer (score 0):

While creating a Virtual Device select the ARM system Image. Others have suggested to install HAXM, but the truth is haxm wont work on amd platform or even if it does as android studio does not supports amd-vt on windows the end result will still be a very very slow emulator to run and operate. My recommendation would be to either use alternative emulator like Genymotion (works like a charm with Gapps installed) or switch to linux as then you will get the benefit of amd-vt and emulator will run a lot faster.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is going to work but you can try this:

It's becoming pretty clear that the emulator team needs to do a better job of disseminating this information about how to use the emulator on AMD on Windows. This question comes up every week it seems.

First, uninstall HAXM.

Next, go here - https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration#vm-windows and follow the instructions for Configuring VM acceleration with Windows Hypervisor Platform

Finally, if you get low framerates in your emulator instances, follow the instructions in the same page for Enabling Skia rendering for Android UI.

Answer (score -2):

In my case, HAXM was already installed in SDK Manager.  But every time I attempted to intelhaxm-android.exe, it would silently fail.

Finally, I extracted the internal installers out of intelhaxm-android.exe in 7-zip.  Copied the three files to another directory and finally got a real installer to run.  Ran without a hitch and HAXM issues were gone.