# Error in launching AVD in Mac

Tags: android, macos, intel

I have OSX Yosemite 10.10 with an Intel i5 processor. I installed Android SDK and Eclipse. It works but the problem is that when I Create AVD launch it it shows this error:

```
 Starting emulator for AVD 'Nexus4-18-xhdpi'
 emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!
 Please ensure Intel HAXM is properly installed and usable.
 CPU acceleration status: HAX is not installed on this machine (/dev/HAX is missing).
```

I am new to android programming and have no clue how to solve it or look into /dev/Hav. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error in launching AVD](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26355645/error-in-launching-avd)

Comment: Please can you elaborate? or what steps should I take to make it run? Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As the error says, you have to install HAXM, which can be found [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager).

Answer (score 14):

From https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/installation-instructions-for-intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-mac-os-x

Under Extras, check the box next to Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM).

[Install]

The SDK Manager will download the installer to the "extras" directory, under the main SDK directory. Even though the SDK manager says "Installed" it actually means that the Intel HAXM executable was downloaded. You will still need to run the installer from the "extras" directory to finish installation.

Answer (score 10):

You need to navigate to

```
/YOUR_SDK_PATH/extras/intel/Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager/
```

Then install the HAXM dmg file.

Comment: Just wanted to comment that I did have to manually run the .dmg and it's relative installer on my Mac before this would work. Simply installing the package and running the installer script in the folder was not enough. Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

Go to

> Window>Android Sdk Manager

1. then in the last section you will find extras expand it
2. then you will find intel (x86) HAXM installer
3. check the check box and click install package.
4. Accept the license agreement and click install.
5. After installing restart your eclipse.

Now you can run AVD

All the best :)

Comment: The latest version Android SDK has intel version 1.1.0 which does not work with OSX Yosemite 10.10. Refer the answer link and get the latest version 1.1.1 HAXM. It will get installed over and replace 1.1.0 and works!!

Answer (score 0):

If you run the following command, you will allow ALL UNSIGNED KEXT to be loaded. Know your system.

> sudo nvram boot-args="kext-dev-mode=1"

**Reboot and reinstall HAXM.**

Answer (score -2):

Following worked for me on mac Android Studio

Installed HAXM Installer

Android studio -> SDK manager -> Launch standalone SDK manager -> Extras -> Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM Installer), rev 6.0.5

https://monosnap.com/file/ArPKwS6qPk651S5wvRgGGGtaMn3YOn