# Android Studio LogCat - No Connected Devices

Tags: android, logcat

After last Android Studio update, LogCat doesn't recognize my devices anymore (showing No Connected Devices). Windows is able to recognize them as always.
I only use Android Studio to log the device's activity, I build the APK from outside.

Please help, I need to log my apps to be able to debug them and fix the problems on the external engine.

Comment: try re-installing device drivers

Comment: Just to confirm, Did u see in the dropdown list your device entry is there or not?

Comment: I reinstalled the device's drivers. The dropdown is empty after last update :-/

Comment: Solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42902260/how-to-solve-unable-to-locate-adbillegalargumentexception-in-android-studio/

Answer (score 13):

You can file Menu select Invalidate Caches /Restart

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was:

Settings > Languages & Frameworks > Android SDK

On the right pane, you see "Android SDK Location:". There was an error with the location. I clicked "Edit" on the right of the text input for location, and Android Studio offered some updates that solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the drivers for your device then it most probably will show your devices and logs in logcat menu

Comment: This should be a comment rather than an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You try Select tab Help in menu, then click Check For Update. It work for me

Answer (score 0):

In "Device Manager" click on the three dots related to your emulator and click on "Wipe Data". Then run your application again.
[image]