# When connecting android device to android studio, it's not recognizing it, and it's showing that it's unable to locate adb.. what's the problem?

Tags: android, android-studio, adb, usb-debugging

When connecting android device to android studio, it's not recognizing it, and it's showing that it's unable to locate adb.. what's the problem?

I tried to uninstall the platform tools, and it didn't work!

[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0BaVN.jpg)

[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y0kDE.jpg)

Comment: Did you enable developer mode and usb debugging on the phone?

Comment: yes ofcourse @Mitulátbáti

Comment: Can't post it as comment. Have you checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39036796/unable-to-locate-adb-using-android-studio) and/or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27301960/errorunable-to-locate-adb-within-sdk-in-android-studio?noredirect=1&lq=1)?

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same problem. Nothing I do will get ADB to start. Here are some things that have been helpful for other people:

1. Obviously, make sure you have installed SDK tools from the SDK manager
2. Make sure you have installed OEM USB drivers available on the Android Studio site
3. Check that ADB has not been quarantined by anti-virus programs
4. Check that ADB has been moved from appdata to another folder location. For some people it does not work well in the default location. Maybe consider C:\SDK\platform-tools. Ensure Studio knows where you've moved it -- put the path in the SDK manager.
5. Try starting ADB as administrator. Try starting Android Studio as Admin.
6. Try starting ADB from a command prompt.
7. Try Removing SDK tools and reinstalling them.
8. Make you are connecting to a USB 2.0 port and not 3.0
9. Try different USB cables
10. Make sure your mobile device is in developer mode and that USB debugging is on