# Android Studio - Unable to locate ADB

Tags: android, android-studio, adb, android-virtual-device

I know the question is repetitive but none of the answers worked for me.
Whenever I try to launch the virtual device in the Android Studio I get the error **unable to locate adb**.

1. The adb.exe and two other dll files are not missing and they are in the right place;
2. My anti-virus is disabled;
3. I tried reinstalling platform-tools;
4. I tried reinstalling the whole Android Studio
   but it still does not work;
5. The sdk path is fine. I'm really stuck.

*Note: OS is Windows.*

Comment: Have you tried manually setting a path to adb.exe in the PATH environment variable? By setting a path to an executable file in the PATH environment variable you make command reachable from any part of your system. Not clear from your question what solutions you have tried already.

Comment: Thank you for your solution. How can I manually set the path?@JeneaVranceanu

Comment: In Settings under Appearance - System Settings - Android SDK you can set the path to "Android SDK Location"

Comment: @Thommy Still Not Working

Comment: @behnam.m, here is where adb.exe is located: [question link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35854238/7210237). Here is how to update the PATH variable (look under **Windows** caption): [link](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.xml).

Comment: @JeneaVranceanu, All done. But I still get the error.

Comment: Ok, open windows terminal, move to the platform-tools directory using `cd` command. Use `dir` command. Do you see in the result list adb/adb.exe file? Note: after changing the PATH variable you should restart your PC if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: To test if you correctly added `adb` command to the PATH variable open windows terminal and type `adb devices`. You should get an empty line after `List of devices attached` if there are no emulators running or devices connected to your computer.

Comment: @JeneaVranceanu, Yes I see adb.exe file in the platform-tools directory.

Comment: @JeneaVranceanu, I exactly get `List of devices attached` and the empty line.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62129354/7210237) are a couple of probably useful answers. Take a look at both of them.