# Android Emulator Don't Run My Apps and shows me Android SDK built for x86 64(mobile) instead of my emulator's name

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, dart, emulation

When I started to emulator [I started the emulator here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WwrJs.png) then it works but I can't run my apps [It shows me like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bidue.png) . When I try to open emulator at avd manager, it gives me an error like that [like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJE0R.png). I uninstalled platform-tools then installed again. it didn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `wipe data` of your emulator first.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at the following two stack overflow questions which may help:

[“unable to locate adb” using Android Studio [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39036796/unable-to-locate-adb-using-android-studio)

[Error:Unable to locate adb within SDK in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27301960/errorunable-to-locate-adb-within-sdk-in-android-studio)

tldr; It's likely to be an issue with avast or another virus scanner.

BTW: There's pretty strong sentiment in this community that you shouldn't be using Avast anyways, considering their history of harvesting data without consent.

Comment: I am using windows defender. I looked at windows defenders logs it did not delete anything in android studio