# Emulator shows an error 'unable to locate adb'

Tags: android-studio, flutter, emulation

While using an android studio I am stuck in running the emulator. While opening the emulator, it shows an error 'unable to locate adb' it cant run. please provide some solution. As I already uninstall and install android a couple of times but the error still exists. I also delete and copy and file but the problem not resolved.

Thanks

Comment: `abd`? or `adb`?

Comment: Yeah, its adb, updated in the question as well. Thanks for noting.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["unable to locate adb" using Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39036796/unable-to-locate-adb-using-android-studio) or this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27301960/errorunable-to-locate-adb-within-sdk-in-android-studio

Answer (score 0):

When in Android Studio, click the AVD button (top right). Once the device is already opened, click the run button and it should work.

[image]