# Error when running the emulator on Flutter in Android Studio

Tags: android, windows, flutter, dart, android-emulator

When running the emulator on Flutter in Android Studio adb.exe exists in AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools, but I get an error saying "Unable to locate adb."

Also, pressing the "Open Android Emulator: ~" button causes the following error:

`Error Opening Emulator`

`emulator: ERROR: Running multiple emulators with the same AVD is an experimental feature. Please use -read-only flag to enable this feature.` .

What should I do?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/taaey.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

That alert comes up very often but the emulator starts up nevertheless. If the emulator doesn't start, click the down button(next to the play button for your emulator in the AVD manager) and select stop/disable to stop the process and try again.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, I tried to stop and restart the emulator and still get the same error as the picture.

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39036796/unable-to-locate-adb-using-android-studio

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this while running Cygwin on Windows with a repo I'd cloned using the Cygwin git. It looks as if Flutter launches things differently from regular Android Studio.

I was able to solve this with:

```
cd \users\(me)\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools
chmod -R u+x *
```

(That's the Cygwin /usr/bin/chmod on my path.) After that, adb started in a Flutter project.