# cant launch emulator on Android Studio - Unable to locate adb err

Tags: android, android-studio, react-native

Can't run any android app because it is unable to locate adb. When I click on "launch this AVD in the emulator", I get an error message "Unable to locate adb". I did look in the Android/Sdk/platform-tools, I have an "adb" executable. I tried to uninstall the folder and reinstall it - didn't help.
I use Android Studio 4.1.1 on Windows.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you added it to your path?

Comment: yep, I added the platform tools to path

Comment: But did you add the `exe` to the path?

Comment: added just now, tried to lounch the emulator again and I still get the same error "Unable to locate adb"

Comment: Restart PC? I always find on Windows I have to restart the computer in order for the path updates to take effect

Comment: I just did a restart, unfortunately it did not solve the problem

Comment: Have you set your SDK location in Project Structure?

Comment: yes, the sdk location is set in project structure

Answer (score 0):

I suppose your error happened several reasons.

- First, didn't find adb.exe in system path.
- Second, the antivirus remove or blocked your adb.exe.
- Third, adb.exe is damaged.
- Fourth, some other reason.

Open Studio settings-->System settings --> Android SDK --> select SDK tool tab -->> select "Android SDK platform tool" and install.

You can refer this url.
["unable to locate adb" using Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39036796/unable-to-locate-adb-using-android-studio)

Comment: Already did that and I still got the same error. If it helps, when I run on cmd "adb devices" when my phone attached with USB, the computer recognize my device

Comment: if you want to check adb, you can run command prompt and enter 'adb' in command.