# Android Studio 4.1 Flutter doesn't recognizing android emuator

Tags: flutter, android-studio, android-emulator, android-studio-4.1, flutter-run

**Flutter unable to run app**

`No connected devices found; please connect a device, or see flutter.dev/setup for getting started instructions.`

[image]

[image]

Comment: did you check this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39036796/unable-to-locate-adb-using-android-studio

Comment: Yeah I am able to run abd command from android studio and platform tools are also installed.

Comment: what does `flutter doctor -v` say?