# Android Studio: "Unable To Locate ADB" and emulator screen goes wrong , Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, android-emulator, adb

I've tried to run my android studio emulator, but pop up "Unable to locate adb" always appear on my screen and after that my emulator was in crash. I've tried to delete and make new emulator, but I've got the same result. Can some one help me about this problem?

strong text[Unable To Locate ADB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tOwYw.png)

[my pc specification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iTZNK.png)

Comment: Go here https://stackoverflow.com/a/47854210/13997210

Comment: I've tried it too but nothing change on my emulator

Comment: Have you disabled your antivirus?

Comment: I've disabled my antivirus, And It still didnt works. 
Or there is a problem with my graphic?

Comment: @RavindraS.Patil I've tried it too but nothing change on my emulator

Comment: @gtxtreme I've disabled my antivirus, And It still didnt works. Or there is a problem with my graphic?

Comment: Hi. Can you please share the specifications of your PC or any other details? It would be helpful for us to understand if the problem may be because of low resources.

Comment: @PreetShah oke, I've added pc specification details https://i.stack.imgur.com/iTZNK.png

Comment: Or maybe it's all because of power supply problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Deployment Issues

**Verify that the Android SDK can connect to your emulator**. To verify emulator connectivity, use the following steps:

1.Launch the emulator from the **Android Device Manager** (select your virtual device and click Start).

2.Open a command prompt and go to the folder where **adb** is installed. If the Android SDK is installed at its default location, **adb** is located at **C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe**; if not, modify this path for the location of the Android SDK on your computer.

3.Type the following command in shell:

```
adb devices
```

4.If the emulator is accessible from the Android SDK, the emulator should appear in the list of attached devices. For example:

```
List of devices attached
emulator-5554   device
```

### Hardware acceleration issues

5.If the emulator does not appear in this list enter the following command:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\emulator\emulator-check.exe" accel
```

(You can verify that hardware acceleration is enabled and which acceleration method the emulator is using.Whether you are using Hyper-V or HAXM for hardware acceleration, you may run into configuration problems or conflicts with other software on your computer.)

This command assumes that the Android SDK is installed at the default location of **C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk**; if not, modify the above path for the location of the Android SDK on your computer.

### Hardware acceleration not available

If Hyper-V is available, a message like the following example will be returned from the **emulator-check.exe accel** command:

```
HAXM is not installed, but Windows Hypervisor Platform is available.
```

If HAXM is available, a message like the following example will be returned:

```
HAXM version 6.2.1 (4) is installed and usable.
```

### Hyper-V issues

In some cases, enabling both **Hyper-V** and **Windows Hypervisor Platform** in the **Turn Windows features on or off** dialog may not properly enable Hyper-V. To verify that Hyper-V is enabled, use the following steps:

6.Enter powershell in the Windows search box.

7.Right-click Windows PowerShell in the search results and select Run as administrator.

8.In the PowerShell console, enter the following command:

```
Get-WindowsOptionalFeature -FeatureName Microsoft-Hyper-V-All -Online
```

If Hyper-V is not enabled, a message similar to the following example will be displayed to indicate that the state of Hyper-V is Disabled:

```
FeatureName      : Microsoft-Hyper-V-All
DisplayName      : Hyper-V
Description      : Provides services and management tools for creating and running virtual machines and their resources.
RestartRequired  : Possible
State            : Disabled
CustomProperties :
```

9.In the PowerShell console, enter the following command:

```
Get-WindowsOptionalFeature -FeatureName HypervisorPlatform -Online
```

If the Hypervisor is not enabled, a message similar to the following example will be displayed to indicate that the state of HypervisorPlatform is Disabled:

```
FeatureName      : HypervisorPlatform
DisplayName      : Windows Hypervisor Platform
Description      : Enables virtualization software to run on the Windows hypervisor
RestartRequired  : Possible
State            : Disabled
CustomProperties :
```

10.If Hyper-V and/or HypervisorPlatform are not enabled, use the following PowerShell commands to enable them:

```
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Hyper-V -All
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName HypervisorPlatform -All
```

After these commands complete, reboot.
Now try to run your Android Studio Emulator.

Comment: Please go to C:\Users\USER_NAME\AppData\Local\Google\AndroidStudio\log\idea file and try to find out the error shown.

Answer (score 0):

May be due to Hyper-V issues. Try:

[Troubleshooting Android Emulator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/android-emulator/troubleshooting?pivots=windows)

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged. Links can break over time rendering the answer meaningless. Please summarize the linked information to help future readers.