# ADB rejected shell command (logcat --help): closed

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-emulator

I run simple project called Happy birthday of Google developer training on Android Studio and got this message. How to fix that?

- ADV : Pixel 3XL API 29
- Android studio Arctic Fox 2020.3.1

The message:

```
ADB rejected shell command (logcat --help): closed 
Failed to startmonitoring emulator-5554
```

Comment: is there any useful suggestion when searching for "ADB rejected shell command" in a search engine?

Comment: @Lino I also receive "unable to locate adb" in this case and try the solution multiple time but not work https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39036796/unable-to-locate-adb-using-android-studiot, then I download a platform-tools from google dev, but still my ADV not work, then I create new ADV with lower API and Screen resolution, then it resolved.