# Can't start flutter project on android emulator

Tags: flutter, android-emulator

So I'm currently working on a flutter app in android studio. My problems begins when I want to display it on an android emulator.
First of all the ads is never locatable (I found a work-around). And when I try to run the project this is the problem:

[image]

Easy approach would be to delete android studio and pull a new intact version, but that's not how I want to solve this problem.
Can someone help me interpret this error message and solve this problem?

Comment: rebuild your project and try again

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39036796/unable-to-locate-adb-using-android-studio

Comment: already tried both of this

Answer (score 2):

Your Problem could have something to do with the firebase bom version your are using, leading to a crash when requesting a FCM token.
Try changing your "com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:28.0.1" in app/build.gradle to com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:27.0.0.