# Unknown connection error with adb.exe in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, sdk, adb

I was trying to test project on a device but got **Error:Unable to locate adb within SDK**. Using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27301960/errorunable-to-locate-adb-within-sdk-in-android-studio) guide I've tried to reinstall [platform-tools]  in SDK manager and added path to SDK library (Windows 7). But that didn't work. Now, after lunching project on a device I have following:

1. File adb.exe just disappears from the [platform-tools] folder
2. I get this notification in Event Log:

> 14:19 Unable to obtain result of 'adb version' 14:25  Executing tasks:
>   [:app:assembleDebug] 14:25    Adb connection Error:????????? ????
>   ????????????? ???????? ???????????? ??????????? 14:25 Connection
>   attempts: 1 14:25 Connection attempts: 2 ...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling Android Studio? I wouldn't normally advice this, but since Android Studio should not be that big of a deal to reinstall with enough internet capacity and you can even keep your preferences, I guess you maybe should try it. I don't know an answer to your specific problem though.

Comment: @creativecreatorormaybenot yeh, thanks. doing it right now. I'll make feedback when done

Comment: After connection with adb, antivirus put adb.exe into quarantine. Works fine now

Comment: Yeah, I had the same issue, although mine just didn't start so I couldn't relate to your error message!