# IllegalArgumentException: Unable to locate adb

Tags: android

I Have A Sony Xperia Android Phone . I Installed (Updated )ADB File Through Device Manager Other Devices , Still Gettting That Error

Answer (score 0):

It is not because of your device.

It can be happen at some circumstances. Try these fixes below.

- Fix your ADB location path from your project preferences
- If you have open Eclipse, close it. It causes conflicts.
- Some Antivirus programs like AVG, blocks ADB and causes this.
- Unistall Platform-Tools using SDK Manager, remove all platform-tools\ directories and reinstall it

If any of these do not work, check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27301960/errorunable-to-locate-adb-within-sdk-in-android-studio).