# Error:Failed to complete Gradle execution. Cause: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: android, android-studio

I know same questions are already asked but they are not helping me.
I am getting 2 fatal errors.

### Error 1

```
Unable to locate adb  
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to locate adb
at com.android.tools.idea.run.editor.DeployTargetPickerDialog.<init>(DeployTargetPickerDialog.java:137)
at com.android.tools.idea.run.editor.ShowChooserTargetProvider.showPrompt(ShowChooserTargetProvider.java:97)
at com.android.tools.idea.run.AndroidRunConfigurationBase.getDeployTarget(AndroidRunConfigurationBase.java:486)
at com.android.tools.idea.run.AndroidRunConfigurationBase.getState(AndroidRunConfigurationBase.java:300)
at com.intellij.execution.runners.ExecutionEnvironment.getState(ExecutionEnvironment.java:158)
at com.intellij.execution.runners.BaseProgramRunner.execute(BaseProgramRunner.java:55)
at com.intellij.execution.runners.BaseProgramRunner.execute(BaseProgramRunner.java:50)
at com.intellij.execution.ProgramRunnerUtil.executeConfiguration(ProgramRunnerUtil.java:118)
at com.intellij.execution.impl.ExecutionManagerImpl.start(ExecutionManagerImpl.java:122)
at com.intellij.execution.impl.ExecutionManagerImpl.access$300(ExecutionManagerImpl.java:69)
at com.intellij.execution.impl.ExecutionManagerImpl$3.run(ExecutionManagerImpl.java:539)
at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.runSafely(QueueProcessor.java:223)
at com.intellij.util.Alarm$Request.runSafely(Alarm.java:418)
at com.intellij.util.Alarm$Request.access$700(Alarm.java:343)
at com.intellij.util.Alarm$Request$1.run(Alarm.java:385)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl$2.run(TransactionGuardImpl.java:303)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$FlushQueue.runNextEvent(LaterInvocator.java:410)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$FlushQueue.run(LaterInvocator.java:399)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:762)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:98)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:715)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:732)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:827)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:655)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:365)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

### Error 2

```
Unable to locate adb within SDK  
com.intellij.openapi.diagnostic.Logger$EmptyThrowable
at com.intellij.openapi.diagnostic.Logger.error(Logger.java:134)
at org.jetbrains.android.sdk.AndroidSdkUtils.getDebugBridge(AndroidSdkUtils.java:536)
at org.jetbrains.android.sdk.AndroidSdkUtils.activateDdmsIfNecessary(AndroidSdkUtils.java:436)
at com.android.tools.idea.run.AndroidRunConfigurationBase.getState(AndroidRunConfigurationBase.java:265)
at com.intellij.execution.runners.ExecutionEnvironment.getState(ExecutionEnvironment.java:158)
at com.intellij.execution.runners.BaseProgramRunner.execute(BaseProgramRunner.java:55)
at com.intellij.execution.runners.BaseProgramRunner.execute(BaseProgramRunner.java:50)
at com.intellij.execution.ProgramRunnerUtil.executeConfiguration(ProgramRunnerUtil.java:118)
at com.intellij.execution.impl.ExecutionManagerImpl.start(ExecutionManagerImpl.java:122)
at com.intellij.execution.impl.ExecutionManagerImpl.access$300(ExecutionManagerImpl.java:69)
at com.intellij.execution.impl.ExecutionManagerImpl$3.run(ExecutionManagerImpl.java:539)
at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.runSafely(QueueProcessor.java:223)
at com.intellij.util.Alarm$Request.runSafely(Alarm.java:418)
at com.intellij.util.Alarm$Request.access$700(Alarm.java:343)
at com.intellij.util.Alarm$Request$1.run(Alarm.java:385)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl$2.run(TransactionGuardImpl.java:303)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$FlushQueue.runNextEvent(LaterInvocator.java:410)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$FlushQueue.run(LaterInvocator.java:399)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:762)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:98)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:715)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:732)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:827)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:655)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:365)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

I have already installed emulator but it is showing no emulator installed.

[image]

I have uninstalled android studio and reinstalled again but it does not help. How to solve it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27301960/errorunable-to-locate-adb-within-sdk-in-android-studio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me,

1. I have downloaded the latest version of SDK Tools in:
    https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools.html
2. I extracted the file into Android Studio SDK's directory (in
   my case is "e:/sdk/"). But it will rewrite the old files with the
   new one.
3. Deleted platform-tool.backup folder
4. open the terminal in Android Studio. run this :cd e:/sdk/platform-tools

Done :)

Answer (score 0):

open Studio settings-->System settings --> Android SDK --> select SDK tool tab -->> select "Android SDK platform tool" and install