# Android Studio doesn't find the adb

Tags: android, android-studio

After my Anti Virus program deletes my `adb.exe` file out of the folder:

> C:\Users\Moritz\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools

I can not run my Android projects, cause this file is missing.

I tried to copy this file back into this folder but the access is blocked by windows. I have admin rights. What can I do? Can Android Studio download this file again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make sure you don't encounter issues due to folder overwriting you may want to delete previous

> {InstallationPath}\Android\Sdk\platform-tools

Open the SDK manager in the Android Studio , switch to SDK tools tab and and select/install the Android SDK Platform-tools.

Also, just to make sure antivirus doesn't mark that file again , you need to whitelist that entire folder with you antivirus system

For more details on installation/download refer to the answer here:-  [Error:Unable to locate adb within SDK in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27301960/errorunable-to-locate-adb-within-sdk-in-android-studio/32758227)

Comment: It works but first I had to delete the C:\Users\Moritz\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools folder