# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to locate adb in Android Studio 3.4.1

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.4

I have updated Android Studio to 3.4.1 but when i try to run my project it shows

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to locate adb

I tried with killing adb process, also tried reinstall studio. but still facing same issue.. It is not working with 3.4.1 version

I have already installed android sdk tools

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error:Unable to locate adb within SDK in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27301960/errorunable-to-locate-adb-within-sdk-in-android-studio)

Answer (score 0):

Try to refresh sdk by Tools->SDK Manager -> SDK Location ->Edit

Answer (score 0):

I tried different ways but did not get any solution. Finally I download Sdk Tools and replaced it. then restarted Android Studio. it worked.

https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools.html