# Android Studio Unable to Locate adb Emulator fails to launch device

Tags: android, android-studio

Hi I am having trouble launching a virtual device. Im getting the error in the image and the device is frozen. I have tried deleting platform tools reinstalling both with sdk manager and manually. I have no idea what to do any help would be appreciated.

Update: still not working I have reinstalled android studio updated computer checked windows defenders nothing works.

[Android Studio Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dcTCx.jpg)

[sdk settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vSmxh.png)

Comment: check this question :
https://stackoverflow.com/q/27301960/9152105

Comment: I tried reinstalling platform tools it did not fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I reinstalled android studio, reinstalled project tools, switched to intelij, and created new device and it started working. I guess the reinstating the device did the fix for me.