# HMS Cloud Debugging not recognised as device in Android Studio

Tags: flutter, android-studio, adb, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

I'm trying to run HMS Cloud Debugging in Android Studio, but there's a problem: when the emulator is launched, the device does not appear as a running device (see img below).

[image: no devices img]

There is an error log that is for sure related to the issue, but I can't seem to understand it, given that adb is properly installed (platform-tools)

The log, while starting Mate 30 device:
[image]

which indicated that there's something wrong with adb.

When I run `which adb`, the output is:

> /Users//Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb

so the PATH is set.

So, what is causing this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You are advised to check whether the ADB service fails to be started in the following event logs.

[image]

[image]

If yes, the port is occupied.Kill the process that occupies the port and restart the Android Studio may help you with your issue.

Comment: I have edited my question to show the error logs more clearly.
I've also tried all the restarts and processes releases that you advised and the same error is shown. I remind you that I can run the emulator, but can't run my debug app in the emulator, since it does not appear as a device in AndroidStudio.

Comment: hey@fff,Could you please provide your OS version, Toolkit version number, and Toolkit logs?You can take the log like this. https://i.stack.imgur.com/HcFma.png

Comment: Sure, I'm working on a macOS Big Sur 11.2.3, Toolkit v5.2.0.300 and here are the logs from restarting AndroidStudio to launching Cloud Debugging -> https://pastebin.com/RbF8vgxH

Comment: Hey @shirley, any new insights? Thanks

Comment: hi@fff,Sorry for the late reply.may i ask are your adb environment variables correctly configured? And what is the echo after you enter adb on the macOS?

Answer (score 0):

It seems the adb environment is not setup correctly. Please confirm adb could be used in Android Studio Terminal environment. Once that is running, the device selection should show up.

Following link has details about checking and setting adb environment for Android Studio:
[Error:Unable to locate adb within SDK in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27301960/errorunable-to-locate-adb-within-sdk-in-android-studio)