# Run my application emulator give me error

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio

### This is image

[image]

---

the path for me of SDK is True and try change tools platform but the same thing

Comment: This question is duplicated with this https://stackoverflow.com/a/27596281/9600076

Comment: open Studio settings-->System settings --> Android SDK --> select SDK tool tab -->> select "Android SDK platform tool" and install

Comment: Ravindra S. Patil the same thing