# Android Studio no link to Huawei Debugging device. Device can launch, but no appear in device selected list

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

> Error : adb file is null , please check the adb exist in Android sdk.
> Android emulator can start

---

- Android Studio 4.2.1  Build #AI-202.7660.26.42.7351085
- JDK: 11.0.8
- OS: Mac OS X 11.5.1
- Android Studio Plugin : HMS Toolkit version: 6.0.0.300
- SDK tools : Android SDK Platform-Tools 31.0.3 (latest)

Check adb using terminal.

```
adb version
```

- Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41
- Version 31.0.3-7562133
- Installed as /Users/mar***/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb

I had research [**HMS Toolkit** is support Android Studio version until 4.2.1](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/Tools-Guides/overview-0000001050060881)
Reinstall Android SDK Platform-Tools.
Why I had try.
[Reinstall Android SDK Platform-Tools](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27301960/11200708).
Reinstall HMS Toolkit.
Reinstall Android Studio.
Problem still occured.

Anyone faced same question? Any solution?

Bellowing is `idea.log` file detail

```
2021-08-03 12:00:48,198 [ 126173]   WARN - openapi.wm.impl.ToolWindowImpl - ToolWindow icons should be 13x13. Please fix ToolWindow (ID:  Cloud Debugging) or icon jar:file:/Users/marslab/Library/Application%20Support/Google/AndroidStudio4.2/plugins/hmstoolkitsdk-tool/lib/common-6.0.0.300.jar!/icons/hiai/remotetest/remote-devices_darcula.png 
2021-08-03 12:00:48,357 [ 126332]   INFO -                         STDERR - [AWT-EventQueue-0] INFO com.huawei.hms.common.util.ProcessUtils - processToList waitFor:1 
2021-08-03 12:00:48,357 [ 126332]   INFO -                         STDERR - [AWT-EventQueue-0] INFO com.huawei.hms.common.util.ProcessUtils - processToList result: [] 
2021-08-03 12:00:48,391 [ 126366]   INFO -                         STDERR - [AWT-EventQueue-0] INFO com.huawei.hms.common.util.ProcessUtils - processToList waitFor:0 
2021-08-03 12:00:48,391 [ 126366]   INFO -                         STDERR - [AWT-EventQueue-0] INFO com.huawei.hms.common.util.ProcessUtils - processToList result: [USER=marslab, __CFBundleIdentifier=com.google.android.studio, COMMAND_MODE=unix2003, LOGNAME=marslab, PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin, SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.yvYbB6OemW/Liste... 
2021-08-03 12:00:48,391 [ 126366]   INFO -                         STDERR - [AWT-EventQueue-0] INFO com.huawei.hms.remotetest.util.AdbUtils -  [HiKey] env: USER=marslab__CFBundleIdentifier=com.google.android.studioCOMMAND_MODE=unix2003LOGNAME=marslabPATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbinSSH_AUTH_SOCK=/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.yvYbB6OemW/ListenersS... 
2021-08-03 12:00:48,392 [ 126367]   INFO -                         STDERR - [AWT-EventQueue-0] INFO com.huawei.hms.remotetest.util.AdbUtils -  [HiKey] adbEvnPath:  
2021-08-03 12:00:48,435 [ 126410]   INFO -                         STDERR - [AWT-EventQueue-0] INFO com.huawei.hms.common.util.ProcessUtils - processToList waitFor:1 
2021-08-03 12:00:48,435 [ 126410]   INFO -                         STDERR - [AWT-EventQueue-0] INFO com.huawei.hms.common.util.ProcessUtils - processToList result: [] 
2021-08-03 12:00:48,445 [ 126420]   INFO -                         STDERR - [AWT-EventQueue-0] INFO com.huawei.hms.common.util.ProcessUtils - processToList waitFor:0 
2021-08-03 12:00:48,445 [ 126420]   INFO -                         STDERR - [AWT-EventQueue-0] INFO com.huawei.hms.common.util.ProcessUtils - processToList result: [USER=marslab, __CFBundleIdentifier=com.google.android.studio, COMMAND_MODE=unix2003, LOGNAME=marslab, PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin, SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.yvYbB6OemW/Liste... 
2021-08-03 12:00:48,445 [ 126420]   INFO -                         STDERR - [AWT-EventQueue-0] INFO com.huawei.hms.remotetest.util.AdbUtils -  [HiKey] env: USER=marslab__CFBundleIdentifier=com.google.android.studioCOMMAND_MODE=unix2003LOGNAME=marslabPATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbinSSH_AUTH_SOCK=/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.yvYbB6OemW/ListenersS... 
2021-08-03 12:00:48,446 [ 126421]   INFO -                         STDERR - [AWT-EventQueue-0] INFO com.huawei.hms.remotetest.util.AdbUtils -  [HiKey] adbEvnPath:  
2021-08-03 12:00:48,455 [ 126430]   INFO -                         STDERR - [ApplicationImpl pooled thread 6] INFO com.huawei.hms.remotetest.task.ApplyPhoneTask - The time internal is : 1627963248451 
2021-08-03 12:00:48,455 [ 126430]   INFO -                         STDERR - [ApplicationImpl pooled thread 6] INFO com.huawei.hms.common.GrsAddress - post success, get grsURl: https://deveco-dra.op.hicloud.com 
2021-08-03 12:00:48,554 [ 126529]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - null 
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.huawei.hms.remotetest.ui.view.PhoneControlView$22.componentResized(PhoneControlView.java:891)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processComponentEvent(Component.java:6480)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6434)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2263)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:5029)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2321)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4861)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:778)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:727)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:95)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:751)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:749)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:748)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:971)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:841)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$null$8(IdeEventQueue.java:452)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.computePrioritized(CoreProgressManager.java:733)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$dispatchEvent$9(IdeEventQueue.java:451)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runIntendedWriteActionOnCurrentThread(ApplicationImpl.java:808)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:505)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.pumpEventsForHierarchy(IdeEventQueue.java:1048)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.util.ProgressWindow.pumpEventsForHierarchy(ProgressWindow.java:225)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.util.ProgressWindow.lambda$startBlocking$4(ProgressWindow.java:214)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runUnlockingIntendedWrite(ApplicationImpl.java:834)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.util.ProgressWindow.startBlocking(ProgressWindow.java:213)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressRunner.lambda$legacyExec$6(ProgressRunner.java:304)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniAcceptNow(CompletableFuture.java:753)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniAcceptStage(CompletableFuture.java:731)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.thenAccept(CompletableFuture.java:2108)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressRunner.legacyExec(ProgressRunner.java:302)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressRunner.submit(ProgressRunner.java:250)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressRunner.submitAndGet(ProgressRunner.java:171)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runProcessWithProgressSynchronously(ApplicationImpl.java:427)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcessWithProgressSynchronously(CoreProgressManager.java:502)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.runProcessWithProgressSynchronously(ProgressManagerImpl.java:83)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runSynchronously(CoreProgressManager.java:354)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.run(CoreProgressManager.java:339)
    at com.huawei.hms.remotetest.ui.view.DeviceMainPanel.runApplyTask(DeviceMainPanel.java:310)
    at com.huawei.hms.remotetest.ui.view.DeviceMainPanel.applyPhone(DeviceMainPanel.java:199)
    at com.huawei.hms.remotetest.ui.toolwindow.DeviceToolWindow.applyPhone(DeviceToolWindow.java:58)
    at com.huawei.hms.remotetest.ui.view.RemoteDevicesDialog.applyDevice(RemoteDevicesDialog.java:316)
    at com.huawei.hms.remotetest.ui.view.RemoteDevicesDialog.onItemClick(RemoteDevicesDialog.java:282)
    at com.huawei.hms.remotetest.ui.view.DevicePanel$4.mouseClicked(DevicePanel.java:212)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6657)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3345)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6419)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2263)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:5029)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2321)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4861)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4918)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4556)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4488)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2307)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2773)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4861)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:778)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:727)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:95)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:751)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:749)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:748)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:971)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchMouseEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:906)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:838)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$null$8(IdeEventQueue.java:452)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.computePrioritized(CoreProgressManager.java:733)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$dispatchEvent$9(IdeEventQueue.java:451)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runIntendedWriteActionOnCurrentThread(ApplicationImpl.java:808)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:505)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:117)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$2.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:190)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:235)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:233)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport.enter(WaitDispatchSupport.java:233)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:1063)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.impl.DialogWrapperPeerImpl$MyDialog.show(DialogWrapperPeerImpl.java:711)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.impl.DialogWrapperPeerImpl.show(DialogWrapperPeerImpl.java:438)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.DialogWrapper.doShow(DialogWrapper.java:1700)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.DialogWrapper.show(DialogWrapper.java:1659)
    at com.huawei.hms.remotetest.action.RemoteDeviceAction.showSelectDeviceDialog(RemoteDeviceAction.java:464)
    at com.huawei.hms.remotetest.action.RemoteDeviceAction.lambda$null$1(RemoteDeviceAction.java:365)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:313)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:776)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:727)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:746)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:971)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:841)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$null$8(IdeEventQueue.java:452)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.computePrioritized(CoreProgressManager.java:744)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$dispatchEvent$9(IdeEventQueue.java:451)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runIntendedWriteActionOnCurrentThread(ApplicationImpl.java:808)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:505)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
2021-08-03 12:00:48,559 [ 126534]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Android Studio 4.2.1  Build #AI-202.7660.26.42.7351085 
2021-08-03 12:00:48,559 [ 126534]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - JDK: 11.0.8; VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM; Vendor: N/A 
2021-08-03 12:00:48,560 [ 126535]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - OS: Mac OS X 
2021-08-03 12:00:48,560 [ 126535]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Plugin to blame: HMS Toolkit version: 6.0.0.300 
2021-08-03 12:00:48,560 [ 126535]  ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Last Action: HMSToolKit.RemoteDevice 
2021-08-03 12:00:48,952 [ 126927]   INFO -                         STDERR - [ApplicationImpl pooled thread 6] INFO com.huawei.hms.remotetest.task.ApplyPhoneTask - get devices responseCode = 200 
2021-08-03 12:00:48,957 [ 126932]   INFO -                         STDERR - [ApplicationImpl pooled thread 6] INFO com.huawei.hms.common.GrsAddress - post success, get grsURl: https://deveco-dra.op.hicloud.com 
2021-08-03 12:00:49,197 [ 127172]   INFO -                         STDERR - [ApplicationImpl pooled thread 6] INFO com.huawei.hms.remotetest.task.RefreshTokenTask - refreshToken responseCode = 200 
2021-08-03 12:00:49,201 [ 127176]   INFO -                         STDERR - [ApplicationImpl pooled thread 6] INFO com.huawei.hms.remotetest.task.ApplyPhoneTask - clientScreenUrl is wss://deveco-dra.op.hicloud.com/hk0-0001/agent/3a29be9c62314c618533337db0e94162?token=Gz5WW2MiKQw6VV9ZWUoLWAwyTwVEIxFaL0VROwsXDwM=&res=540 
2021-08-03 12:00:49,202 [ 127177]   INFO -                         STDERR - [ApplicationImpl pooled thread 6] INFO com.huawei.hms.remotetest.task.ApplyPhoneTask - device sn is java.lang.Object@3a4017fc 
2021-08-03 12:00:49,677 [ 127652]   INFO -                         STDERR - [ApplicationImpl pooled thread 6] INFO com.huawei.hms.remotetest.websocket.ScreenWebSocketEndpoint - ScreenWebSocketEndpoint init finish 
2021-08-03 12:00:49,690 [ 127665]   INFO -                         STDERR - [ApplicationImpl pooled thread 6] INFO com.huawei.hms.remotetest.task.ApplyPhoneTask - Screen Proxy  start successed. 
2021-08-03 12:00:49,691 [ 127666]   INFO - s.common.util.trace.TraceUtils - trace country code :sg 
2021-08-03 12:00:49,692 [ 127667]   INFO - s.common.util.trace.TraceUtils - trace country code :sg 
2021-08-03 12:00:49,705 [ 127680]   INFO -                         STDERR - [ApplicationImpl pooled thread 6] INFO com.huawei.hms.core.main.module.manager.Module - this situation can not happen 
2021-08-03 12:00:49,705 [ 127680]   INFO -                         STDERR - [ApplicationImpl pooled thread 6] INFO com.huawei.hms.core.main.module.manager.Module - this situation can not happen 
2021-08-03 12:00:49,705 [ 127680]   INFO -                         STDERR - [ApplicationImpl pooled thread 6] INFO com.huawei.hms.core.main.module.manager.Module - this situation can not happen 
2021-08-03 12:00:49,706 [ 127681]   INFO -                         STDERR - [ApplicationImpl pooled thread 6] INFO com.huawei.hms.core.main.module.manager.Module - this situation can not happen 
2021-08-03 12:00:49,706 [ 127681]   INFO -                         STDERR - [ApplicationImpl pooled thread 6] INFO com.huawei.hms.core.main.module.manager.Module - this situation can not happen 
2021-08-03 12:00:49,706 [ 127681]   INFO -                         STDERR - [ApplicationImpl pooled thread 6] INFO com.huawei.hms.core.main.module.manager.Module - this situation can not happen 
2021-08-03 12:00:49,710 [ 127685]   INFO -                         STDERR - [ApplicationImpl pooled thread 6] INFO com.huawei.hms.core.main.module.manager.Module - this situation can not happen 
2021-08-03 12:00:49,722 [ 127697]   INFO -                         STDERR - [ApplicationImpl pooled thread 6] ERROR com.huawei.hms.common.util.ImageUtils - /Users/marslab/Library/Preferences/hmstoolkit/hiai/remotetest/icons/phone/mate30pro/mate30pro_bg.png (No such file or directory) 
2021-08-03 12:00:49,753 [ 127728]   INFO -                         STDERR - [WebSocketClient-SecureIO-1] INFO com.huawei.hms.remotetest.websocket.ScreenWebSocketEndpoint - screen onTextMessage{"type":"SUCCESS_CONN","message":""} 
2021-08-03 12:00:49,952 [ 127927]   INFO -                         STDERR - [ApplicationImpl pooled thread 6] ERROR com.huawei.hms.remotetest.ui.view.ScreenJPanel - remote_image_transe_failed:false 
2021-08-03 12:00:50,016 [ 127991]   INFO -                         STDERR - [ApplicationImpl pooled thread 6] INFO com.huawei.hms.common.GrsAddress - post success, get grsURl: https://deveco-dra.op.hicloud.com 
2021-08-03 12:00:50,258 [ 128233]   INFO -                         STDERR - [ApplicationImpl pooled thread 6] INFO com.huawei.hms.remotetest.task.RefreshTokenTask - refreshToken responseCode = 200 
2021-08-03 12:00:50,259 [ 128234]   INFO -                         STDERR - [ApplicationImpl pooled thread 6] INFO com.huawei.hms.remotetest.task.ApplyPhoneTask - clientAdbUrl is wss://deveco-dra.op.hicloud.com/hk0-0001/agent/adb/3a29be9c62314c618533337db0e94162?token=AmMnIg08Kio/UltJUQ8HTSsLTVhSPEkcJCFOCzEUDzk= 
2021-08-03 12:00:50,259 [ 128234]   INFO -                         STDERR - [ApplicationImpl pooled thread 6] INFO com.huawei.hms.remotetest.proxy.AdbProxy - start adb proxy : wss://deveco-dra.op.hicloud.com/hk0-0001/agent/adb/3a29be9c62314c618533337db0e94162?token=AmMnIg08Kio/UltJUQ8HTSsLTVhSPEkcJCFOCzEUDzk= 
2021-08-03 12:00:50,262 [ 128237]   WARN - intellij.openapi.progress.Task - Empty title for backgroundable task. 
java.lang.Throwable
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.Task$Backgroundable.<init>(Task.java:202)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.Task$Backgroundable.<init>(Task.java:192)
    at com.huawei.hms.remotetest.task.UserDelayTimeTask.<init>(UserDelayTimeTask.java:51)
    at com.huawei.hms.remotetest.ui.view.DeviceMainPanel.excuteUserDelayTimeTask(DeviceMainPanel.java:316)
    at com.huawei.hms.remotetest.ui.view.DeviceMainPanel.runApplyTask(DeviceMainPanel.java:312)
    at com.huawei.hms.remotetest.ui.view.DeviceMainPanel.applyPhone(DeviceMainPanel.java:199)
    at com.huawei.hms.remotetest.ui.toolwindow.DeviceToolWindow.applyPhone(DeviceToolWindow.java:58)
    at com.huawei.hms.remotetest.ui.view.RemoteDevicesDialog.applyDevice(RemoteDevicesDialog.java:316)
    at com.huawei.hms.remotetest.ui.view.RemoteDevicesDialog.onItemClick(RemoteDevicesDialog.java:282)
    at com.huawei.hms.remotetest.ui.view.DevicePanel$4.mouseClicked(DevicePanel.java:212)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6657)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3345)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6419)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2263)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:5029)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2321)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4861)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4918)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4556)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4488)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2307)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2773)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4861)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:778)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:727)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:95)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:751)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:749)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:748)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:971)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchMouseEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:906)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:838)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$null$8(IdeEventQueue.java:452)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.computePrioritized(CoreProgressManager.java:733)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$dispatchEvent$9(IdeEventQueue.java:451)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runIntendedWriteActionOnCurrentThread(ApplicationImpl.java:808)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:505)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:117)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$2.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:190)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:235)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:233)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport.enter(WaitDispatchSupport.java:233)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:1063)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.impl.DialogWrapperPeerImpl$MyDialog.show(DialogWrapperPeerImpl.java:711)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.impl.DialogWrapperPeerImpl.show(DialogWrapperPeerImpl.java:438)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.DialogWrapper.doShow(DialogWrapper.java:1700)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.DialogWrapper.show(DialogWrapper.java:1659)
    at com.huawei.hms.remotetest.action.RemoteDeviceAction.showSelectDeviceDialog(RemoteDeviceAction.java:464)
    at com.huawei.hms.remotetest.action.RemoteDeviceAction.lambda$null$1(RemoteDeviceAction.java:365)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:313)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:776)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:727)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:746)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:971)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:841)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$null$8(IdeEventQueue.java:452)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.computePrioritized(CoreProgressManager.java:744)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$dispatchEvent$9(IdeEventQueue.java:451)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runIntendedWriteActionOnCurrentThread(ApplicationImpl.java:808)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:505)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
2021-08-03 12:00:50,306 [ 128281]   INFO - .deployment.AsyncDevicesGetter - adb not found 
2021-08-03 12:00:50,529 [ 128504]   INFO -                         STDERR - [pool-18-thread-1] ERROR com.huawei.hms.remotetest.task.UserDelayTimeTask - excute http request failed, please check your network 
2021-08-03 12:00:50,616 [ 128591]   INFO -                         STDERR - [ApplicationImpl pooled thread 1] INFO com.huawei.hms.remotetest.websocket.AdbWebSocketEndpoint - AdbWebSocketEndpoint init finish 
2021-08-03 12:00:50,621 [ 128596]   INFO -                         STDERR - [ApplicationImpl pooled thread 1] INFO com.huawei.hms.remotetest.proxy.AdbProxy - start adb proxy succeed. 
2021-08-03 12:00:50,621 [ 128596]   INFO -                         STDERR - [ApplicationImpl pooled thread 1] INFO com.huawei.hms.remotetest.ui.view.DeviceMainPanel - cant not found adb path 
2021-08-03 12:00:51,053 [ 129028]   INFO - .deployment.AsyncDevicesGetter - adb not found 
2021-08-03 12:00:51,225 [ 129200]   INFO -                         STDERR - [WebSocketClient-SecureIO-1] INFO com.huawei.hms.remotetest.websocket.ScreenWebSocketEndpoint - screen onTextMessage{"action":"init","width":544, "height":1104} 
2021-08-03 12:00:51,225 [ 129200]   INFO -                         STDERR - [WebSocketClient-SecureIO-1] INFO com.huawei.hms.remotetest.websocket.ScreenWebSocketEndpoint - screen onTextMessage{"rotation":"0","action":"screen","resolution":"AVC540P"} 
2021-08-03 12:00:51,238 [ 129213]   INFO -                         STDERR - [WebSocketClient-SecureIO-1] INFO com.huawei.hms.remotetest.websocket.ScreenWebSocketEndpoint - screen onTextMessage{"type":"SCREEN_RECORD_RSP","message":{"msg":false}} 
2021-08-03 12:00:51,987 [ 129962]   INFO - .deployment.AsyncDevicesGetter - adb not found 
2021-08-03 12:00:52,487 [ 130462]   INFO - .deployment.AsyncDevicesGetter - adb not found 
2021-08-03 12:00:52,990 [ 130965]   INFO - .deployment.AsyncDevicesGetter - adb not found 
2021-08-03 12:00:55,525 [ 133500]   INFO -                         STDERR - [pool-18-thread-1] ERROR com.huawei.hms.remotetest.task.UserDelayTimeTask - excute http request failed, please check your network
```

The bellowing is my path, for easy to see, I split into multiple line, default is one line.
I using **zsh**, references ~/.zshrc.
echo $path

```
/usr/local/opt/php@7.4/sbin 
/usr/local/opt/php@7.4/bin 
/usr/local/bin 
/usr/bin 
/bin 
/usr/sbin 
/sbin 
/usr/flutter 
/Users/mar***/flutter/bin 
/Users/mar***/.gem/ruby/2.6.0/bin 
/Library/Apple/usr/bin 
/Users/mar***/flutter/bin 
/Users/mar***/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin 
/Users/mar***/.pub-cache/bin /Users/mar***/Library/Android/sdk 
/Users/mar***/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools
```

Comment: What does `echo $PATH` say, does it have `platform-tools`?

Comment: Yes, got platform-tools. I had check the folder too. Also got file inside, so do not know reason occur adb not found. Normal android emulator can launch and connected without any problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The log reads: `Plugin to blame: HMS Toolkit version: 6.0.0.300`
... and then it literally continues with `cant not found adb path`:

```
INFO - .deployment.AsyncDevicesGetter - adb not found 
INFO - STDERR - [pool-18-thread-1] ERROR com.huawei.hms.remotetest.task.UserDelayTimeTask - excute http request failed, please check your network 
INFO - STDERR - [ApplicationImpl pooled thread 1] INFO com.huawei.hms.remotetest.websocket.AdbWebSocketEndpoint - AdbWebSocketEndpoint init finish 
INFO - STDERR - [ApplicationImpl pooled thread 1] INFO com.huawei.hms.remotetest.proxy.AdbProxy - start adb proxy succeed. 
INFO - STDERR - [ApplicationImpl pooled thread 1] INFO com.huawei.hms.remotetest.ui.view.DeviceMainPanel - cant not found adb path
```

I've just tried to install the HMS Toolkit on Android Studio version 4.2.2, which complains on startup (but it still kind of works, except some buttons not being well-clickable).
Make sure it downloaded it's resources (this may have been blocked by local firewall) - and make sure that `adb` is on `PATH`.