# Android Studio Emulator Show Error

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk, emulation, android-virtual-device

I Use the latest version of `Android Studio` (Ver1.0.1 - 11 December 2014)
When I try to run the `emulator`, I got this Error :

`emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!
Please ensure Intel HAXM is properly installed and usable.
CPU acceleration status: HAX kernel module is not installed!`

But I think I've already installed what it needs:

[image]

1) I click the Run button ...

[image]

2) The Error

[image]

3) My SDK Manager

Comment: try reinstalling the HAXM form extras

Comment: I've tried, but the same error again

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26355645/error-in-launching-avd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to reinstall `Intel HAXM` (it is in `%android-sdk%/extras/intel/Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager`) and check if it enabled in your BIOS. 
Also (but it is not preferred because slower), you can make your `emulator` to use arm7 image.

Comment: Thanks, So "Installed" word in SDK Manager in front of HAXM doesn't mean that HAXM is installed on my machine, so I have to install it from the path you note.

Comment: `it is not preferred because slower` ... but it helps you write better code. Because if it runs decently on a slow emulator, it will run bettere on a real device (particularly useful for older and slower  devices).

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure the SDK manager actually *installed* the package?

On my Mac the SDK manager only *downloads* it, had to install it manually (see [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/installation-instructions-for-intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-mac-os-x)).

How to install per OS: https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager

Comment: I Use win8.1, it's confusing that SDK manager show me INSTALLED but actually it is just downloaded.