# Not launching avd emulator on android studio in windows 7

Tags: android, android-emulator

emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!
Please ensure Intel HAXM is properly installed and usable.
CPU acceleration status: HAX kernel module is not installed!

I am getting the above error message when i launched my android avd emulator .

i even  installed HAXM installer on your SDK Manager and enabled virtualization on my hcomputer.uninstalled Avast software too.
please help me out to solve this issue.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error in launching AVD](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26355645/error-in-launching-avd)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following commands as admin from a command line:
(assuming you've turned on VT in BIOS)
 
bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off

 bcdedit /set nx AlwaysOn