# How do I fix HAX carnel module issue in Android studio?

Tags: android, sdk, android-studio, android-emulator, bios

I have successfully installed Android Studio from their official homepage.
But the problem is I can't strat my emulator. Once I run the program, it shows the following error in my command window.

```
"C:\Users\Jabir Al Fatah\AppData\Local\Android\sdk1\tools\emulator.exe" -avd Nexus_5_API_21 -netspeed full -netdelay none
emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!
Please ensure Intel HAXM is properly installed and usable.
CPU acceleration status: HAX kernel module is not installed!
```

Now, I have uninstalled the Studio at least 10 times and installed them again. I have searched online about all the possible solution. I have HAXM installer installed  properly in my sdk.
I have enabled the virtualization in BIOS. But none of those really help. 
I wanted to exucute the intelhaxm.exe file. But the problem is I don't find any sdk folder in my drive. I can see the specified derictory for sdk while installing the studio, but in reality that folder is never created and never exist in my drive.

Please help me to find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
Windows 8. Android Studio.
Make sure if virtualization is enable : go through those steps provided below.
```

- Goto setting -> change pc settings-> general->then see on right side
  by scrolling the frame down-> you will see under advance start up
  restart now button press it->then choose an option window will
  open->choose troubleshoot->under troubleshoot choose Advance
  option->then under Advance options choose UEFI Firmware option->then
  press restart->press f10 for BIOS->see the menubar where you will
  find system configuration menu inside it you will see the
  virtualization Technology "enable" it ->now go for exit saving
  changes in exit on menu bar..

  C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager\intelhaxm-android.exe

  (in username : please enter valid user name)

  install it and restart your Android Studio.

  if you make few changes on above process it is same for win 7 and also same for eclipse have fun!!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. You might wanna read this post:
[Error in launching AVD with AMD processor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26355645/error-in-launching-avd)

In particular, after installing HAXM through the SDK manager, which in itself didn't fix the problem, try to run the intelhaxm-android.exe. This showed that I had some hardware virtualization problems (like the error mentioned in the other post).

I'm switching to the Genymotion thingy.

Cheers, B.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually, I found a different solution, as the Genymotion wasn't the right thing for me.

In the AVD manager, I changed the processor type of the AVD to ARM and this doesn't need the HAXM thing at all. This surely doesn't make stuff very fast, but it got me a working emulator. Once it's running, it's not that bad.

Hope this helps.

Cheers!