# Error instaling Intel Emulator Acelerator HAXM

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

Today I downloaded the Android Studio 1.0.1, when I was trying to open the virtual machine I get this error:

```
emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!
Please ensure Intel HAXM is properly installed and usable.
```

looking on the internet i found this topic [Error in launching AVD with AMD processor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26355645/error-in-launching-avd), they said for make sure I have installed HAXM installer on my SDK Manager, I opened the sdk manager and it really is installed, how you can see in above image:

[image]

But it is just a installer, knowing that the HAXM installer is downloaded, I was try to install the HAXM (for make sure that it is really installed), it is in this directory:

```
...{SDK_FOLDER}\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager\intelhaxm-android.exe
```

but when i open the installer i get this error:

[image]

Still folowing the topic "error in launching avd", i tried to execute this command:

```
dism.exe /Online /Disable-Feature:Microsoft-Hyper-V
```

and again i get a error:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Windows\system32>dism.exe /Online /Disable-Feature:Microsoft-Hyper-V

Error: 18

An error occurred while loading DISM. The DISM tool may be corrupt.
Try reinstalling DISM.
```

why is ocurring these errors? how can i solve this for open normally the avd?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intel's virtualization technology `VT-x` is disabled by default. This has to be enabled for the CPU before running the `HAXM` setup.

You need to reboot your PC and enter the BIOS mode. Look under advanced settings and you should find one that lets you enable virtualization for your processor.

[image: Intel VT-x BIOS setting]

Note, if you're running an AMD processor, your BIOS may call it `AMD-V` instead of `VT-x`.

Comment: i cannot find this option in my BIOS, i searched for similar options but i can`t find. My bios is American Magatrends v02.59

Comment: That doesn't look good. I suggest looking through your vendor's website to check if your cpu/motherboard support virtualization or not.

Answer (score 0):

Are you working on an Intel machine or AMD ?

System Requirements for  Intel® Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager"

Hardware Requirements

Intel® processor with support for Intel® VT-x, Intel® EM64T (Intel® 64), and Execute Disable (XD) Bit functionality
At least 1 GB of available RAM
Supported Operating Systems:

Microsoft Windows* 8 and 8.1 (32/64-bit)
Microsoft Windows* 7 (32/64-bit)
Microsoft Windows Vista* (32/64-bit)

Comment: i am working with Intel machine, is 4 GB avaible in RAM memory, my os is Windows 7 64 bit