# Android App development without Virtualization Technology?

Tags: android, android-studio, virtualization

I'm a newbie to Android Application development, just started off by downloading [Android Studio](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#win-bundle) along with [JDK-7](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html) and also installed Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator(HAXM) through SDK manager.

[image]

Now when I try to launch Emulator, I get this error:

`emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!
Please ensure Intel HAXM is properly installed and usable.
CPU acceleration status: HAX kernel module is not installed!`

I tried these [steps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26380900/1463551) from a [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26355645/error-in-launching-avd), but when I try to run the setup located at: **{SDK_FOLDER}\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager\intelhaxm.exe**
I get this exception:

[image]

and when I checked my processor config, I found that it doesn't support Virtualization technology,

[image]

Now my question is, is it possible to use a pc without Virtualization technology feature for Android App Development(Including Emulator)?

Comment: You really don't want to.  Unaccelerated emulators are extremely slow.  Even launching one takes minutes.  If your PC can't handle it you're better off using a real device rather than an emulator.  A real device gives you more realistic results anyway,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the name implies, it is an `Emulator Accelerator`. You can still use the Emulator, its just going to be a bit slower running without `HAXM`.

In my experience, it is OK to use the normal emulator for infrequent debugging but it is too slow, even with HAXM, for serious development, which should be carried out on an actual device.

If you **have** to use an emulator, I'd go with [GenyMotion](https://www.genymotion.com/).

Comment: Is it possible to test it on our actual phone connected through a cable, without generating APK? PC doesn't support virtualization?

Comment: Yes, one can run apps directly from Android Studio on a physical device without generating and transferring an APK.

Answer (score 1):

San', you could try using a super fast and popular emulator known as "GenyMotion". It is for free :). Also, I ran into the VT error myself before when I first installed Android Studio on my new laptop and I was able to successfully resolve it by configuring my BIOS options a bit. It's easy, I can point you to the direction that I took if you want me to.

Comment: thanks for response, as mentioned in the question my pc doesn't support Virtualization technology, hence there's no way that we could use BIOS to turn or/off. correct me if I'm wrong.