# How to install Intel HAXM for Windows XP

Tags: android, haxm

> emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware
>   acceleration! Please ensure Intel HAXM is properly installed and
>   usable. CPU acceleration status: HAX kernel module is not installed!
>   intel(R) pentium(R) Dual CPU E2140 @ 1.60GHz(2 CPUs)

I have run Android emulator in Windows XP. It throws above error.

Have this configuration of processor. How can I solve?

> intel(R) pentium(R) Dual CPU E2140 @ 1.60GHz(2 CPUs)

I have this configuration of processor.

How can I do it or check (Also make sure hyperV off bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off 
XD bit is on bcdedit /set nx AlwaysOn ) this?

Comment: There are so many posts regarding this. Have you tried Googling this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error in launching AVD](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26355645/error-in-launching-avd)

Comment: Try this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26355645/error-in-launching-avd#

Answer (score 2):

For the above given intel bios type/processor ,it doesn't support the  vt-x technology.

for more details,

http://ark.intel.com/products/29738/Intel-Pentium-Processor-E2140-1M-Cache-1_60-GHz-800-MHz-FSB

[image]

Answer (score 1):

First check that it's an Intel processor that supports VT and NX bit (XD) - you can check your CPU # at http://ark.intel.com 
Also make sure hyperV off bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off 
XD bit is on bcdedit /set nx AlwaysOn 
Use the installer from https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager 
If you're using Avast, disable "Enable hardware-assisted virtualization" under: Settings > Troubleshooting. Restart the PC and try to run the HAXM installation again

Answer (score 1):

please check the link it has haxm for windows xp
[link](http://venomvendor.blogspot.in/2012/08/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution.html). I know its too late but if someone needs it. Because the official site has no description for windows xp

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.