# Android studio emulator not working

Tags: android, android-studio, intel

i downloaded android studio. it is working fine but emulator not running showing error;

```
emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!
Please ensure Intel HAXM is properly installed and usable.
CPU acceleration status: HAX kernel module is not installed!
```

I installed HAXM but it can not be installed, saying Intel vitalization technology is turned off. as i enabled it from bios also then i am getting the same error. kindly help me, i will be very thankful to you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error in launching AVD](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26355645/error-in-launching-avd)

Answer (score 2):

You have to enable Intel hardware acceleration from the bios. Try restaring the pc and installing HAXM again.

Comment: did the same thrice. i have uploaded an image. kindly check and reply.

Comment: this post may help you, http://www.sysprobs.com/disable-enable-virtualization-technology-bios. The error is because intel virtualization feature is not activated via Bios config. If dont know how to enter bios config, you need to restart the pc, and press F2 repeatly until you get a configuration screen like the post i just linked.

Comment: i have enabled virtualization technology. it shows that virtualization technology is turned on. still i am getting the same error. btw thanks for help.

Comment: Where is showing the virtualization is enabled? Remember to save and exit from BIOS setup, if u keep getting the same error maybe is not enabled. Well the only advice i can give you is trying to download again the package from intel, https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the SDK manager:
[image]

And install the HAXM installer:

[image]

Comment: what CPU does your emulator have?

Comment: default nexus 5 AP1 21 x86

Comment: Im pretty sure you need to solve the VT-x error you're getting when installing the HAXM first, before trying to solve it in Android Studio

Comment: you may want o either search for this issue, or post a new specific question about this. Unfortunately that issue is not related to android studio or any other IDE

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the hardwares of your emulator from the menu, change it's cpu to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same issue.The problem is that just install Intel x86 Atom System Image.

Tools >> Android >> SDK Manager >> // Check if the Intel X86 Atom System Image is Installed.If not select it n install it.

Hope it helped.

Comment: which all options you checked?could you plz post a screenshot of the stuffs from the extra tab in SDK Manager?

Comment: Actually i am getting error in installing HAXM. once HAXM install then i will proceed further.