# Error by running the app in emulatoor with AndroidStudio

Tags: android, android-studio, windows-7, amd-processor

I have Winows 7 pro with an AMD processor. When I run app with emulator from AndroidStudio, I get:

```
emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!
Please ensure Intel HAXM is properly installed and usable.
CPU acceleration status: HAX kernel module is not installed!
```

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26355645/error-in-launching-avd), but when I run `dism.exe /Online /Disable-Feature:Microsoft-Hyper-V`, I get error

> Funktion "Microsoft-Hyper-V" is unknown

I also not have "Virtualization Technology" in BIOS.

How can I use AndroidStudio with Windows 7 with AMD.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#accel-vm):

> Before attempting to use this type of acceleration, you should first determine if your development system’s CPU supports one of the following virtualization extensions technologies:
>
> - Intel Virtualization Technology (VT, VT-x, vmx) extensions
> - AMD Virtualization (AMD-V, SVM) extensions (only supported for Linux)

Hence, if the documentation is correct, you will not be able to use the x86 emulator on your AMD CPU on Windows 7.

Your options are:

- Use the ARM emulator (slow but works "out of the box")
- Try to follow [the instructions for setting up x86 support](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#accel-vm) anyway, and see if the docs perhaps are out of date
- Try a third-party emulator, like Genymotion, and see if it supports AMD better

Answer (score 0):

You have to install the intel HAXM for the accleration. you have to go to your sdk. then follow the steps:

```
> Go to sdk installed directory 
>extras
>intel
>Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager/
```

install here the intelhaxm-android, it will fix your problem

if its not helpful then you should install  [this](https://www.genymotion.com/#!/download) and [this](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html). This is 100 % faster or you can read more about virtualization on AMD on this Link [AMD Virtualization problem](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#accel-vm)

Comment: After that I get a error message, that virtualisation is not supported. [Image](http://ronasoft.de/bilder_bay/android_error.PNG).