# I can't seem to run my AVD on Android Studio

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I'm getting an error while running my AVD on Android Studio. Below screenshot is the error.

http://i.gyazo.com/cc1d9497b3f504196fe4f78fc6a2932e.png

After doing some Googling, I understand that the HAXM installer needs to be installed from the SDK Manager. I did that (screenshot below)

http://i.gyazo.com/060b1108091d497da3e9e312ec7aedcc.png

Doing some further research, it seems like I need to execute an .exe file from the Android Studio folder. However, the SDK folder seems to be missing for me.

I'm stuck in a loop here, I'm not sure what to do. Is anyone able to assist with this? I enable virtualization in my BIOS but it didn't do the trick. My processor is also supported according to the intel website. Thank you.

Comment: I don't have an exact answer for your issue, but I would HIGHLY recommend using [genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/#!/). Much quicker and reliable emulator.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error in launching AVD](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26355645/error-in-launching-avd)

Comment: Check out this - http://stackoverflow.com/a/26380900/1479511

Comment: "the SDK folder seems to be missing for me" ... <project>-rightclick-<open module settings>-<sdk location>

Comment: just find the sdk and install HAXM driver

Answer (score 1):

Use [Genymotion](http://www.genymotion.com) as your emulator. Fast and reliable. The solution below is from [a possible duplicate question to yours.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26355645/error-in-launching-avd)

---

After you download it and make sure you run the setup located in: `{SDK_FOLDER}\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager\intelhaxm.exe`

Note: in Android Studio, the command `"intelhaxm.exe"` has been changed to `"intelhaxm-android.exe"`

If you get the error `"VT not supported"` during the installation disable Hyper-V on windows features. You can execute this command `dism.exe /Online /Disable-Feature:Microsoft-Hyper-V.` You will also need `"Virtualization Technology"` to be enabled on your BIOS

Comment: if my answer helped you, please accept it by clicking the tick :)

Answer (score 0):

If that doesn't work try the ARM virtual device instead because your PC might not be intel HAXM compatible(mine wasn't). There might be some other options too for other types of virtual devices you can use. I recommend you try the ARM one if it doesn't work.