# Can't run a blank activity in Android Studio (rendering problems)

Tags: android, android-activity, gradle

I'm very close to giving up with Android development. I don't currently have an Android phone so I'm trying to use emulators. In Eclipse, after fixing 500000 bugs/errors I finally managed to get an emulator to launch - but it kept getting stuck on the Android loading screen (even after like 45 mins) so somebody recommended me to use Android Studio.

I downloaded this on my PC, and when I tried to run a blank activity I  got this error: 
[image]

When I tried to actually play around with the activity, I got a rendering error:
[image]

I saw some stuff online that said to use a downgraded Android version for the error to go away - however, I only have 2 versions as you can see and none of them are working.

I tried downloading/installing Android Studio on my laptop too and got the exact same problems. What is going on? I have spent 2 days trying to run a blank activity now and am really on the verge of just giving up. Any ideas?

EDIT: Trying out Jorge Casariego's suggestion but cannot find Open Modules when I right click

[image]

Comment: Do you have the JDK 7 installed on your machines? If I record correctly, JDK 8 doesn't work right now with Studio...

Comment: If I type java -version in my command prompt it tells me that my current version is 1.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resolve this issue follow the following steps :

1. Go to your app folder under Navigation section.
2. Right Click -> Open Module Settings
3. Set Compile with SDK Version as **API 22 or below** (Lollipop)
4. Set Build version as **21.1.2**
5. Clean + Build your Project

to use the new M preview, you'll need to also use Android Studio 1.3 Preview (from the canary channel).

Comment: @eyesenberg is belowe "Compare With"

Comment: Lol not sure how I missed that. For build version I only have 23.0.0 rc1 and 22.0.1, I tried 22.0.1 and still the same problem :( The following classes could not be instantiated:
- android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)

Comment: which version of Android Studio are you using?

Comment: Nvm its working now, thanks. I get this error when I try to run the app but I'll deal with it another time: emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!
Please ensure Intel HAXM is properly installed and usable.
CPU acceleration status: HAX kernel module is not installed!

Comment: @eyesenberg Perfect!! Now you need to do this http://stackoverflow.com/a/26380900/2091181

Comment: Nice, I got it working. Thanks a lot for you time, I feel like this is a big accomplishment :D

Answer (score 2):

To downgrade your SDK, you need to download a different SDK version. To do this, you need to run the SDK Manager which is the 4th image from the right: [image: the 4th image from the right.]

This will allow you to download different versions of Android, allowing you to get API 19/20/21, which should fix your issue.

I get this rendering problem all the time and I've been developing for almost 2 years now, with over 10 months on android studio. These rendering problems are only for the activity preview, which usually isn't very helpful at all anyway. <s>If you don't have an Android device, my best suggestion would be to download the GenyMotion emulator. It is 1000x better than the built in emulator, and even has a plugin for android studio that allows you to run it from within the IDE. If you need to check how a layout works, I would recommend just running the app in the emulator, as you will get a much better idea of how things look anyway, rather than trying to approximate it with the layout previewer.</s>

**Edited 6/10/18:** 
The packaged emulator has been updated extensively and now performs much better. For that reason, I've removed the link to the 3rd party tool. I realize my intention at the time was to be helpful, but having a link to a 3rd party tool in a stackoverflow question seems inappropriate, especially given the reason for highlighting it is outdated.

Comment: Ah I've had bad luck in that everything I install or download just doesn't work as it should and comes with a ton of errors and bugs. Thanks for this, I will try the emulator as a last resort if there aren't any other suggestions that fix the problem. I don't know why I'm struggling so much to run a blank activity - Android seems really messed up. edit: just saw your edit, I'll give that a go!

Comment: Unfortunately there are still some growing pains with Android still, especially with getting the IDE set up. Once you get this all running though, everything else is a breeze.

Comment: I hope so. Cannot resolve symbol "R" - I'm getting this error out of nowhere (haven't touched anything) and it doesn't go even after building/cleaning. Why do these things happen lol

Comment: To be honest, it seems like you made some errors in installing Android Studio in the first place. I would completely clean out any trace of Android Studio and reinstall from scratch. Cannot resolve symbol R is an error occurs when the IDE cannot build your R file, which is a mapping of all your resources by their id's. It is a generated file, and when there are internal errors in your IDE, it will struggle to build it.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like it happens because you are updated Android build tools to "24.0.0 rc1" but not update gradle build plugin to 1.3.0-beta1 version.

Make sure that you have in **yourProjectFolder/build.gradle**

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0-beta1' // or 1.2.3
}
```

And in **yourProjectFolder/mainModuleName/build.gradle** you have

```
android {
    ...
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.0 rc1" // or 23.0.1
    ...
}
```

or as a variant use last stable versions of build tools

Comment: @eyesenberg its really simple. In your project root folder you'll have build.gradle file just make sure that you have "classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0-beta1'" line there

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem too. Because I named my App the wrong thing. It has a  "-" character in the app name. Ex: Web-ViewDemo. It causes a wrong location, so android studio can't do anything totally right 100%.

In short, try to rename your app!