# Android Studio AVD emulator error, can't find sdk path

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-sdk-tools

I've installed Android Studio following TheNewBoston tutorial instructions. When trying to launch the default Nexus AVD in the emulator I get this error message:

Cannot launch AVD in emulator.
Output:

```
emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!
Please ensure Intel HAXM is properly installed and useable.
CPU acceleration status: HAX karnel module is not installed!
```

Of course, I've installed Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator in Android SDK Manager but I can't find SDK at the default location mentioned in some answers `(C:\users\username\AppData\Local\Android\sdk).`

Please help me start developing.
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error in launching AVD with AMD processor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26355645/error-in-launching-avd-with-amd-processor)

Answer (score 0):

This has already been answered under:
[Error in launching AVD with AMD processor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26355645/error-in-launching-avd)

- Sometimes you may have to enable the "enable hardware virtualization
  in bios"

Below is a URL which shows how (Windows):
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YzaCOZAYtJs

- In UNIX:

http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/13/html/Virtualization_Guide/sect-Virtualization-Troubleshooting-Enabling_Intel_VT_and_AMD_V_virtualization_hardware_extensions_in_BIOS.html