# AVD manager in Android Studio stopped working

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device

I recently installed Android Studio, and could successfully use AVD Manager, at beggining. But suddenly it stopped working due to following error:

```
emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!  
Please ensure Intel HAXM is properly installed and usable.  
CPU acceleration status: HAX kernel module is not installed!
```

I have tried to install & run HAXM manually, but problem is that I have Windows 7 Home Premium and don´t have Hyper-V option. Reasonably, I cant install HAXM!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error in launching AVD](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26355645/error-in-launching-avd)

Comment: I followed most of instructions in that topic, but it doesnt work, as all solutions  eventually lead to Hyper-V option, which I don´t have!

Answer (score 0):

Whether you have VT is a function of the BIOS and processor. You don't have to have Windows hypervisor to use Virtualization, in fact you have to turn hypervisor off on systems that have it. Check your BIOS and download HAXM from - https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager
Also turn off Avast is you're using it for antivirus