# Can not run emulator in android studio in windows 7

Tags: android, intel

I'm beginner in android studio and i have installed latest android studio in my pc, which is windows 7.

Now when i try to run emulator it shows, following error.

```
emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!
Please ensure Intel HAXM is properly installed and usable.
CPU acceleration status: HAX kernel module is not installed!
```

I've googled and found the solution for it and i've tried to install Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager from the android sdk path.

But when i try to install the exe it shows following error, see 
image

I've installed Intel Processor identification, and checked visualization is enabled, 
see image

So can any one tell me why emulator is not running in my pc?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error in launching AVD](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26355645/error-in-launching-avd)

Comment: I don't see the images you are referring to.