# Intel HAXM installation error in VMWare

Tags: android, virtual-machine, intel, haxm

My own processor supports virtualisation:

[image]

I think i have activated it also in my bios settings.

And it is the info page of my processor of the vmware virtual machine i use (*9.0.2 build-1031769*)

[image]

Still, when i try to install Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager in order to start my android virtual devices, i take the following error:

[image]

What should i do?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26355645/error-in-launching-avd/26380900#26380900

Comment: i have installed it using SDK Manager, it resides in that corresponding directory, i have no Hyper-V and VT activated in BIOS.

Comment: And in windows? Did you activated it?

Comment: upon activating in BIOS? How should i do?

Comment: Read that post. Which I guess you didn't despite I posted it here.

Comment: i had read it (even comments) and i have done all.

Comment: So I guess `dism.exe /Online /Disable-Feature:Microsoft-Hyper-V` didn't work for you.

Comment: Yes, as i said, i have also that feature not enabled.

Comment: Thus i mean, i dont see that feature even in Windows Features, both in my own pc and in my virtual machine

Comment: Do you have any anti virus?

Comment: no, even the windows defender and firewall are closed

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I simply had to check 'virtualize intel vt-x/ept or amd-v/rvi' in my machine settings.

[image: Enable Intel VT Virtualization]

Comment: This now works for VMware Workstation starting with version 12/12.5. (my answer predates VMware exposing the same feature in VM settings)

Answer (score 5):

Are you trying to install that *in* a VM? Nested virtualization isn't enabled out-of-the-box, VMware clients (Player & Workstation) have supported it for a while now. (And it looks like your CPU is new enough to support it well)

Shut the VM down, close the VMware application & add the following line to your `.vmx` file:

`vhv.enable = "TRUE"`

*(If Workstation/Player later complains about the `vmx` being corrupted, your version doesn't support it. Remove the line to fix the file.)*

[VMware hypervisors support it](https://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2034803) so that you could test ESXi out in a local Workstation machine. However, it's also known to work for other virtualization OSes. (I used it for Hyper-V in Windows 8.1 so I could develop Windows Phone apps without upgrading my Windows 7 workstation)

Comment: This worked for me when trying to run an Android emulator inside an OSX VMware image running on Windows 10 host machine.

Comment: This worked for me inside an OSX VMWare image running on Linux Mint 18.2 host machine. It went from complaining that HAXM is not supported to letting me download install HAXM. Unfortunately the emulator is still mind numbingly, soul crushingly, career devastaingly slow.

Answer (score 1):

I think this error occurs when Virtual Technology (VT-x) is not enabled in the BIOS settings. You should go to the BIOS menu & enable it to create Virtual Device