# How to enable x86 based Android-emulator on windows 10

Tags: android, visual-studio-2017

Developing xamarin Project, just started with new win 10 (virtual machine) and VS2017. I get this when I start the emulator (API 25)

[image]

**I want to enable x86-based Android emulator, so I can get that alluring 10x performance boost**

Before, I could simply go to Android SDK Manager and enable HEXM (below), but in win 10 it says "not compatible with windows ".

[image]

I went to Intels page and downloaded a driver as suggested on [this SO-question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41092207/the-intel-x86-emulator-accelerator-haxm-installer-revision-6-0-5-is-showing-no), but no difference (install_silence.bat was run as admin, see comments in post)

Any one got that working? (win10/VS2017)

EDIT: I have not Hyper-V installed

Comment: uninstall Hyper-V and try again to get HAXM working

Comment: forgot to mention that, I have not Hyper-V installed

Comment: post your HW specs and make sure VT-x is enabled in BIOS/UEFI.

Comment: @magicandre: VT-x is enabled/virtualized (note that Im running on a virtual machine), Sure, what hardware are u referring to? my host(dev machine) or my emulator?

Comment: ok, the VM is the issue. what you want is called nested virtualization. how do you run the VM? VirtualBox, vmware? Hyper-V?  if you use a newer [VMware version, try this setting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44955831/1466046).

Comment: Yes, thats checked on my VM. Im using VMWare. I have had another VM, just the same, where I had no problem, but I dont have that VM anymore, so I cant compare them. Other postsa have indicaded that it is Win10 that causes the problems.

Comment: which Windows 10 Build/Version do you use?

Comment: win Enterprise 10.0.16299, Build 16299

Comment: I have no real idea how to solve this.

Comment: @magicandre1981: Thanks anyway for your time and ideas :)