# Android Studio in Google Cloud VM

Tags: android-studio, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, virtualization

I have installed Android Studio in Windows 2012 Server machine on Google Cloud. But, I cannot run Emulator on it. It shows the below error.

"HAXM doesn't support nested virtual machines"

Comment: May I ask why did you do that?

Comment: Just for testing

Comment: Take a look at this, may be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32308519/intel-haxm-installation-error-in-vmware

Comment: Also this, is just like your problem. But it is for a local windows VM:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38528076/android-studio-virtual-device-on-a-windows-7-vm-not-compatible/42283740

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider that nested virtualisation is not enabled out of the box for Compute Engine instances.
Therefore you need to [enable it manually](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/enable-nested-virtualization-vm-instances), however it is not available yet for Windows instances as you can check in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/enable-nested-virtualization-vm-instances) page:

> Nested virtualization does not currently support Windows instances.

Comment: Is it supported in Ubuntu instances ?

Comment: Yes, quoting again from the documentation `Nested virtualization is only supported for KVM-based hypervisors running on Linux instances. ESX and Xen hypervisors are not supported.` Therefore I do not see any reason why it shouldn't work for Ubuntu. However consider that it is still a Beta feature and it is not covered by any SLA or deprecation policy and may be subject to backward-incompatible changes.