# how to set up the AVD for android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to run my app on the simulator on Android Studio. I am new to Android btw. This is the message I got

"emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!
Please ensure Intel HAXM is properly installed and usable.
CPU acceleration status: HAX kernel module is not installed!
"
But I remembered clearly that I did install the simulator on SDK manager. Any ideas? Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Android SDK Manager, scroll down to the "Extras" section and install the `Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer)` package.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure that you have installed all the packages in SDK manager (especially extras).
Secondly, if there are other issues have a look at this thread:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/30129536/2507646

One of the issues is enabling virtualization in BIOS settings on your laptop. I had the same issues, and that was the resolution.