# Error in Android Studio: "ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!"

Tags: android, android-studio

I started recently using Android Studio and am stuck with this error message:

> x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!
>   Please ensure Intel HAXM is properly installed and usable.
>   CPU acceleration status: HAX kernel module is not installed!

Any idea how to resolve it?

I did some search on the issue am having and I think it has to do with changing my ANDROID_SDK_ROOT environment variable to the original value, but no clue how to do so.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error in launching AVD](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26355645/error-in-launching-avd)

Answer (score 0):

Not resolveable if you have an AMD processor on Windows, at least as far as I know.

If you have an Intel processor, enable the virtual extensions in your bios (called VT, if available).
If you are on windows also install HAXM via the Android SDK manager. (also install it, the SDK manager will only download it: {SDK_FOLDER}\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager\intelhaxm.exe)

Disable hyper-V if you are on Windows 8 or above using: `dism.exe /Online /Disable-Feature:Microsoft-Hyper-V`

Genymotion is an alternative for AMD users.

Possible duplicate of [Error in launching AVD with AMD processor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26355645/error-in-launching-avd)

Comment: I do believe it might be a duplicate of the thread you tagged. I do apologies about this. Should i delete the question?

Comment: If you want to, but I just flagged it for being a duplicate. Someone will surely take care of it. :-)

Comment: How can i exactly enable my intel vt x?

Comment: In your BIOS look under Features. There should be an entry called "Virtualization Technology" or "VT support" or "VT-x Support" or something along the lines of those. Enable it.

Comment: Note that not all Intel processors support VT, especially if your computer is older or lower end. Better check up on that as well.