# how to enable virtualization technology in windows 8.1 - 64-bit system

Tags: android, hardware, intel, hardware-acceleration

[image]

I have enabled Virtualization technology in BIOS and have even tested using the Intel identification tool it shows that virtualization technology is enabled in my computer though I am facing this problem and I am not able to run the emulator in android studio.I have even tried installing intel-haxm and faced the problem as shown. Can anyone help me solve this issue.

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26355645/error-in-launching-avd

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have an Intel processor that supports VT and NX bit (XD) - you can check your CPU # at http://ark.intel.com 
use the following command lines: 
 bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off 
 bcdedit /set nx AlwaysOn 
If you're using Avast, disable "Enable hardware-assisted virtualization" under: Settings > Troubleshooting. Restart the PC and try to run the HAXM installation again
Then for installation Use the installer from https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager