# what was the last version of android studio that didn't require hardware acceleration to run the emulator?

Tags: android, version

Android studio currently requires hardware acceleration. Just want to see if I can get an older version of as so I can run emulator since my computer does not have hardware acceleration at all.

Comment: Are you referring to the Graphics acceleration (GPU emulation) option of the emulator? It is NOT mandatory at all.

Answer (score 0):

you can use other emulator like Genymotion https://www.genymotion.com

i often use my Nexus 5 (Lollipop -> now Marshmallow) for testing, and Genymotion for older version.

i use genymotion because my processor is AMD, so i cannot use HAXM because its intel based

VT-x or AMD-V capable CPU is required for genymotion 
https://www.genymotion.com/#!/download

Answer (score 0):

it need acceleration only for x86 system images.
refer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26355645/error-in-launching-avd) for details on that.

It does not require hardware acceleration for ARM system images.

use images marked as `armeabi-v7a`

[image]