# how to reslove the error for android

Tags: android

[image: error image]

Cannot launch AVD in emulator.

Output:

```
emulator: WARNING: could not load skin file 'C:\Users\System-5\AppData\Local\Android\sdk1/C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\plugins\android\lib\device-art-resources/nexus_5/layout', using built-in one
emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!
Please ensure Intel HAXM is properly installed and usable.
CPU acceleration status: HAX kernel module is not installed!
```

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26355645/error-in-launching-avd

Answer (score 0):

Install Intel HAXM package first, and the retry.

Comment: Have you enable the VT mode?