# Why isn't my Android app working when I test it on a real device?

Tags: cordova, android-emulator, ionic-framework

I'm building an Android app with Ionic Framework, and am trying to run it on a real device with USB debugging, like in these tutorials:

> http://www.neilberry.com/how-to-run-your-ionic-app-on-real-devices/?s=2015-08-24-how-to-run-your-ionic-app-on-real-devices
>
> http://junerockwell.com/how-to-run-ionic-on-real-devices/

**Step-1**

> `$ ionic platform add android`
>
> `$ ionic build android`

After adding the Android platform and building an APK with the above commands, it works correctly with no error. So, I try the next step:

**Step-2**

I connected device and PC via Debugging mode to run android devices. I ran the command `ionic run android`. I get the below error messageL

> `$ ionic run android`
>
> `ANDROID_HOME=C:\Android\sdk
>   JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\java\jdk1.8.0_25
>   WARNING : No target specified, deploying to emulator
>   WARNING : no emulator specified, defaulting to Nexus_5_API_23_x86
>   Waiting for emulator...
>   emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!
>   Please ensure Intel HAXM is properly installed and usable.
>   CPU acceleration status: HAX kernel module is not installed!`

How can I solve this problem?

**List of my ionic info:**

> `$ ionic info`
>
> `Your system information:
>    Cordova CLI: 5.4.1
>    Gulp version:  CLI version 3.9.0
>    Gulp local:   Local version 3.9.0
>    Ionic Version: 1.2.4
>    Ionic CLI Version: 1.7.13
>    Ionic App Lib Version: 0.6.5
>    OS: Windows 8.1
>    Node Version: v4.2.4`

Comment: Why don't you use Android Studio for this task? It is easier to handle then using the command line.

Comment: I want to get really install process and really run device.

Comment: **Did you get the answer?**

Comment: I solved, after installed my phone's driver on PC, check devices list that  `adb devices`.

Comment: try to install android studio then open the platform/android folder from you source folder then debug it and resolve your error this the best way to rectified you errors

Comment: @LwinKyawMyat If you solved your problem, please close your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error isn't related to [ionic frameworks](https://ionicframework.com) because `HAXM installer` isn't installed on **Android SDK Manager**.

> This question already has an answer here: 
>   [Error in launching AVD with AMD processor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26355645/error-in-launching-avd-with-amd-processor).

Answer (score 1):

I don't use ionic, I use cordova. In cordova you call the emulator by:

```
cordova emulate android
```

and to run the app on a device:

```
cordova run android --device
```

Maybe you try:

```
ionic run android --device
```

Comment: In ionic, "ionic run android" will try to run on the connected Android device. If no such device is found, it will launch the emulator (similar to calling "ionic emulate android").

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try running `adb start-server`. I know I need to do this first before being able to see my device in `chrome://inspect/#devices`. You of course need adb which probably comes from the Android SDK.