# Error while starting emulator in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, haxm

The error message I get is:

> emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware
>   acceleration! Please ensure Intel HAXM is properly installed and
>   usable. CPU acceleration status: HAX kernel module is not installed!

Comment: as i have installed intel haxm for 6 marshallow. what to install please help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26355645/error-in-launching-avd

Comment: Best answer is here http://stackoverflow.com/a/34282302/4919237

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26355645/error-in-launching-avd/27997670#27997670), the complete steps are:

1) Open SDK Manager (In Android Studio, go to Tools > Android > SDK Manager) and Download Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer) if you haven't.

2) Now go to your SDK directory (C:\users\username\AppData\Local\Android\sdk, generally). In this directory Go to extras > intel > Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager and run the file named "intelhaxm-android.exe".

> In case you get an error like "Intel virtualization technology
>   (vt,vt-x) is not enabled". Go to your BIOS settings and enable
>   Hardware Virtualization.

3) Restart Android Studio and then try to start the AVD again.

It might take a minute or 2 to show the emulator window.

For more Detail visit here.

[Error in launching AVD with AMD processor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26355645/error-in-launching-avd/27997670#27997670)

Comment: You can add http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26355645/error-in-launching-avd/27997670#27997670 link