# skd manager and Intel HAXM

Tags: android, haxm

Hi Guys I am new to Android Studio. So I was trying to create a new project, and the virtual phone won't show up and it give me this error:

```
emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!
Please ensure Intel HAXM is properly installed and usable.
CPU acceleration status: HAX kernel module is not installed!
```

I checked online and it seem like I have to install Intel HAXM. So I went to Tools->Android->SKD Manager, and I got this...
[image]

What should I do?

Comment: Are you working from home?

Comment: This may be the solution, follow this link.
http://stackoverflow.com/a/27997670/4584028

Comment: @Pooya I'm working on company's computer

Comment: Maybe there is proxy server or firewall that refuse your connection you can talk to your IT department

Comment: @BalrajAllam The problem is I cannot download HAXM right now...

Comment: @VivekMishra Yeah I've been searching this topic for an hour and all those solutions are not working for me

Comment: you can download it from 3rd party sites too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, the alternative way to install this is, you have to download HAXM installer and install externally(instead of one provided by android studio or ecilpse) from intel website. Try this one. This may work.

https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager

Answer (score 1):

Go to your `SDK` directory and right click on `SDK Manager.exe` then open the compatibility tab and check the option to run it as administrator, it will most probably solve your issue

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is if you are using AMD processor. Intel virtualisation wont work. I suggest you save yourself the trouble and get Genymotion. It is free for personal use and it is dealing with virtualisation issues.