# Android Studio will not work on Windows 10

Tags: android

I have tried for many days to use Android Studio using Windows 10 and just get an error message saying cannot launch AVD emulator.
Emulator: ERROR x86 emulation requires hardware acceleration!
Please ensure Intel HAXM is properly installed and usable.
CPU acceleration status: HAXM is not installed on this machine
Why am I getting the message and how do I resolve the problem.
Feel deeply let down by this software!!!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error in launching AVD](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26355645/error-in-launching-avd)

Comment: So basically you are complaining about Android Studio and Windows 10 because you haven't read the docs and forgot to install Intel HAXM, as it is clearly stated in the error message. Instead of searching for it you chose to post it here. To make things short: install Intel HAXM and enable Virtualization in your BIOS, if you have an Intel processor.

Comment: @Chris Dotchin I had the same issue when I upgraded to Windows 10. Skizo's answer below will fix the problem for you. It just has to do with the default AVD that is created when you install Android Studio. You could delete that AVD if you wanted and just create another one that didn't require x86 hardware emulation if you didn't want to install the HAXM drivers/software

Comment: @Chris Dotchin did you solve the problem? Have you checked my answer?

Answer (score 1):

Well as the error says :

> Emulator: ERROR x86 emulation requires hardware acceleration! Please ensure Intel HAXM is properly installed and usable.

You need to install [`Intel HAXM drivers`](https://software.intel.com/es-es/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager), and also make sure that in your `SDK Manager` you've installed `Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer)`, restart your `Android Studio` and you are done.