# AVD failed to load

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

Just Installed Android Studio 2.1. At the finalizing the installation error shows for AVD Manager not install properly. 
SDK Manager shows HAXM installer installed successfully. But whenever I open AVD manager, in action column shows failed to load.

OS:Win7

Comment: If you have AMD processor you may wish to look at this [Error in launching AVD with AMD processor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26355645/error-in-launching-avd-with-amd-processor). Personally I use GenyMotion.

Comment: System is Macbook Pro with dual boot (MacOS X+ and Win7) and Android Studio was installed in Win7. Does it matter?

Comment: I'm not sure. However, the issue appears to be around **Virtualisation Technology** which has to be enabled in the BIOS. So if you can't enable **VT** in BIOS then it's probably not going to work. Note I'm no expert but I went along that route and ended up getting/installing/using genymotion.

Answer (score 1):

Go to sdk-->extras-->intel-->Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_manager

and install intelhaxm-android.exe

hope it will work.