# when my project run(Cannot launch AVD in emulator)and then run the message Error while waiting for device. why?

Tags: android-layout, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

No such file or directory.
Launching app-Error while waiting for device: The emulator process for AVD was killed)

Comment: Question is not clear. When you launch the emulator, you will be getting an error message on why it failed to start the emulator. Please post that information to get some answers. Similar issue - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26355645/error-in-launching-avd-with-amd-processor

Comment: post your AVD configs